# Alternative for inheritance in python

Tags: python

How to save code duplication in the following scenario ?

say `A`and `B` are two classes having a common function(say) `name`

```
class A(object):
    name = 'foo'

    @property
    def name(self):  # the common function
        return self.name
```

similarly B

```
class B(object):
    name = 'bar'

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name
```

**One way would be to make a class from which both of them inherit from, and define `name` there.**

**Any good alternatives ?**

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139508.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really determined to avoid inheritance, just define a function outside of either class:

```
def get_name(object):
    return object.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A(object):
    name = 'foo'

    def get_name(self):  # the common function
        return self.name

class B(A):
    pass
```

In this case `B` would inherit from `A`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't have B inherit from A?

```
class B(A):
    name = 'bar'
```

Comment: Well, A isn't inheriting from B here. Just B from A, where is the issue with regular inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are decorating `name` with `@property`, I am assuming you want this to be an instance variable. If you want this to return a more private variable, let's call it `_name`, you have to do:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = 'foo'

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

You can't have both a variable and a function have the same name, since the latter will simply override the former. If you want a base class that takes care of this, it would look like this:

```
class HasName(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

class A(HasName):
     def __init__(self):
         self._name = 'foo'

class B(HasName):
     def __init__(self):
         self._name = 'bar'
```

You can also call the constructor in `HasName`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `self.name` stands in for a more complex method, the easiest way to cut down on duplicated code is to move the function out to the module and have it take an arbitrary object as a parameter.  Then, if you still want to tie the method directly to the class, you can add a short method that dispatches to the module function.

```
def _name(obj):
    return obj.name

class A(object):
     # ...

     @property
     def name(self):
         return _name(self)

class B(object):
     # ...

     @property
     def name(self):
         return _name(self)
```

Note that this will *not* work well if `A.name` and `B.name` have completely different behaviors.  If the `_name` function starts checking the type of the object given, reconsider whether you really want to abstract that functionality in the first place.