# How to add parameters to Django class based generic view decorators?

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-1.3, django-class-based-views

I have written a decorator to display success message on object creation:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def success_message(klass):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(klass, self).form_valid(form)
        messages.success(self.request, 'Object added successfully')
        return response

    klass.form_valid = form_valid
    return klass
```

and use it to decorate class based generic view:

```
@success_message
class BandCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Band
```

Now I want to parameterize the decorator so this is possible:

```
@success_message('Band created successfully.')
class BandCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Band
```

How do I do it? I tried adding `message` parameter to `success_message` but the compiler complained about parameter count mismatch so I figure there must be another  way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python class decorator arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492068/python-class-decorator-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have to use closure:

```
def decorator(arg):
    def wrap(klass): ...
    return wrap
```

because your call is evaluated to

```
class BandCreateView(CreateView): ...
BandCreateView = @success_message('Band created successfully.')(BandCreateView)
```

note double call

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I previously did this kind of thing as a mixin, but a decorator makes more sense (and is a bit less of a hassle to add to classes). You might like to get the form instance's verbose name like the following, to eliminate the need to pass a message to the decorator:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def ucfirst(value):
    return value[0].upper() + value[1:]

def success_message(klass):
    __orig_form_valid = klass.form_valid
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = __orig_form_valid(self, form)
        messages.success(self.request, _("%(object)s \"%(object_name)s\" was saved successfully.") %
                         {'object': ucfirst(form.instance._meta.verbose_name), 'object_name': unicode(form.instance)})
        return response

    klass.form_valid = form_valid
    return klass
```

This will produce a success message something along the lines of:

Customer "ACME Inc." was saved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Parameterless decorator is declared as a **`class -> class`** function.
Decorator with parameters is declared as a higher order **`args -> (class -> class)`** function.

It takes parameters and returns a **function that will take class and return class** (i.e. the “simple” decorator).

#### Explanation

An answer from a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/problem-python-decorators-with-parameters/5929165#5929165) by [t.dubrownik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679897/t-dubrownik) literally saved me.

> Anyway, the syntax for decorators with arguments is a bit different—**the decorator with arguments should return a function that will take a function and return another function**. So it should really return a normal decorator.

Although he is talking about function decorators, the concept is applicable to class decorators as well.
Here is what I got:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def success_message(message):
    def actual_decorator(klass):
        def form_valid(self, form):
            response = super(klass, self).form_valid(form)
            messages.success(self.request, message)
            return response

        klass.form_valid = form_valid
        return klass

    return actual_decorator
```

Note how `actual_decorator` itself repeats the parameterless version  of `success_message` and how `success_message` is now a higher order function because its return value is function itself.