# Python decorators in classes with extra parameters

Tags: python, python-decorators

I read this

[one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263451/python-decorators-in-classes)
and this
[another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492068/python-class-decorator-arguments)

but I'm not doing it right with parameters

```
class decoratortest:
    def dec(func):
        def wrapper(self,*args,**kwargs):
            func(*args,**kwargs)
            func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @dec
    def printer(self,a):
        print(a)
        
    def dectest(self):
        self.printer('hi')
x = decoratortest()
x.dectest()
```

I get the usual positional error argument.  What's the right syntax so I can print hi twice?

For the future, this worked:

```
class decoratortest:
    def dec(func):
        def wrapper(self,*args,**kwargs):
            func(self,*args,**kwargs)
            func(self,*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @dec
    def printer(self,a):
        print(a)
        
    def dectest(self):
        self.printer('hi')
x = decoratortest()
x.dectest()
```

very tricky, you dont' type self in the decorator, but you do in the underlying wrapper and func items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `self` explicitly, since `func` is a reference to a regular `function` object, not the `method` object that `self.printer` produces (via the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)):

```
def dec(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can put your decorator outside of the class

```
def dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class decoratortest:
    @dec
    def printer(self, a):
        print(a)

    def dectest(self):
        self.printer('hi')


x = decoratortest()
x.dectest()
```

Output:

```
hi
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class decoratortest:
    def dec(func):
        def wrapper(self,*args,**kwargs):
            func(*args,**kwargs)
            func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @dec
    def printer(self,a='hi'):
        print(a)
        
    def dectest(self):
        self.printer('hi')
        
x = decoratortest()
x.dectest()
```

Added a default value for decorator when argument is not specified and it worked.