# Variable as statement in python?

Tags: python

I was reading some python code and come across this. Since I mostly write C and Java (And variable as statement doesn't even compile in these language) I'm not sure what it is about in python.

What does `self.current`, the "variable as statement", means here? Is it just some way to print the variable out, or this is a special grammar thing / practice in dealing with exceptions in python?

```
class PriorityQueue():

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.current = 0   

    def next(self):
        if self.current >=len(self.queue):
            self.current
            raise StopIteration

        out = self.queue[self.current]
        self.current += 1

        return out
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the rest of the class?

Comment: It doesn't really do anything at all, it can probably be freely removed without any consequence. It doesn't even print anything. Hard to say without knowing the context of that member, maybe it's doing some sneaky black magic but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: It doesn't do anything by itself. Maybe `current` is a method with a property decorator, and the method has a side-effect? But that's a very odd way to write code.

Comment: It's from a "complete a priority queue" fill-in practice, and this is the only 2 methods provided counting constructor in. I'll add the init() in.

Comment: In that case, it does nothing. More on SpiXel's answer, which is really good :)

Comment: Unless you throw out Occam's Razor, `self.current` is, and remains, an integer.

Comment: Side-note: contrary to what you claim, this is *totally* allowed in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't do anything, the only way it can do anything in particular, as @Daniel said in the comments, is if `self.current` refers to a [property method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). Something like the following:

```
class X():
    @property
    def current(self):
        mail_admins()
        return whatever

    def next(self):
        ...
```

This way, calling `self.current`, would actually do something.

But anyways its definitely not considered good practice since a property is just that, a property, if it's supposed to do something, it should be method.

Comment: Sometimes it can actually be useful, such as forcing a lazy property to be computed now. But as in his example it has been computed right on the previous line, either the invocation has side effects, which is bad, or it doesn't, and calling it a second time will be useless.

Comment: Yes, it's a great insight. It's like getter and setter in multiple other languages.

Comment: The in-place addition in the next clause makes this unlikely ([though possible!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987949/how-to-implement-iadd-for-a-python-property)).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this can be used for checking whether the attribute/method actually exist in the passed parameter. May be useful for input sanity check.

```
def test(value):
    try:
        value.testAttr
    except AttributeError:
        print "No testAttr attribute found"
```