# __iadd__ in Python with read only property

Tags: python

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987949) deals with `__iadd__` on Python read-write properties. However, I'm struggling to find the solution for read-only properties.

In my MWE we have a read-only property `Beta.value`, returning an `Alpha` instance. I imagine I should be able to use `__iadd__` on `Beta.value` because the *returned* value is mutated in-place, and no change is made to `Beta` itself, much like the "`beta.value.content +=`" line preceding it. However the following code crashes with an `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

**Is it possible to use `__iadd__` on read-only properties?**

```
class Alpha:
    def __init__( self, content : int ) -> None:
        self.content : int = content


    def __iadd__( self, other : int ) -> "Alpha":
        self.content += other
        return self


class Beta:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.__value: Alpha = Alpha(1)


    @property
    def value( self ) -> Alpha:
        return self.__value


beta = Beta()
beta.value.content += 2
beta.value += 2
```

Comment: Related: [Append to a list defined in a tuple - is it a bug?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29747224)

Comment: It is even worse than that: `beta.value` raises an error (which is expected) but increase `beta.value.content`!

Comment: @Aran-Fey A nice reminder of why `x += 1` works for immutable types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be tricked by adding a special setter for the property that only accepts the original *object*.

Class `Beta` would become:

```
class Beta:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.__value: Alpha = Alpha(1)

    def _get_val( self ) -> Alpha:
        return self.__value
    def _set_val( self, val: Alpha):
        if not (val is self.__value):            # only accept the existing object
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
    value = property(_get_val, _set_val)
```

With that hack/trick on, you can successfully use:

```
>>> beta = Beta()
>>> beta.value.content
1
>>> beta.value = Alpha(2)               # property IS read only
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#86>", line 1, in <module>
    beta.value = Alpha(2)
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 9, in _set_val
    raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> beta.value.content                  # and was not changed by an assignment attempt
1
>>> beta.value += 2                     # but accepts augmented assignment
>>> beta.value.content
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that people often forget with in-place operators is that their use always involves an assignment. You can see this intuitively in `Alpha.content` (or any `int` or `str` really): integers are immutable, but the operation works. It's much easier to forget about this step for something like `Alpha` or `list`, where the in-place operator just returns `self`. Just remember that the operator can return anything at all, and the result has to be bound to the original name. What's happening here is basically this:

```
x = beta.value
x = operator.iadd(x, 2)      # Totally fine
beta.value = x # You can  imagine how this would be a problem...
```

A direct consequence of this is that you'll see the changes in `beta.value` despite the error.

You're always welcome to bypass the reassignment by first assigning to a temporary variable, i.e., running the first two lines shown above explicitly. Just remember that while in your case `Alpha` is mutable and really modifies itself in-place, that's not a requirement for the general case:

```
x = beta.value
x += 2
```

works as intended. However,

```
x = beta.value.content
x += 2
```

does not, since `int.__iadd__` inevitably returns a new reference.

Answer (score 0):

Operator += works with the whole assignement, the whole line. Therefore there is a ambiguity: is your object calling __iadd__ or a setter property ? Check this out:

This does not work:

```
beta.value += 2  # calls setter property (which does not exist)
```

But this works:

```
value = beta.value  # calls getter property
value += 2  # calls __iadd__ (upon the returned object from the getter)
```

NB: This frustrates me but it has to be like that; otherwise, how would we know which method is called and how will the code behave ?

Have fun :)