# Python Functions Can Have Attributes?

Tags: python, function, attributes, decorator

I'm very new to Python and I don't understand how functions themselves can seemingly have attributes.  In the code below, there is a function called f, and later in the code, something by the name of f.count is referenced.  How can a function, namely f, have a .count?  I'm getting an error message of: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count' on that line, so it obviously doesn't have that attribute yet.  How do I give it that attribute?

```
def fcount(n):
    print n.__name__


@fcount
def f(n):
    return n+2

for n in range(5):
    print n
    #print f(n)

print 'f count =',f.count #THE LINE CAUSING THE ERROR MENTIONED ABOVE

@fcount
def g(n):
    return n*n

print 'g count =',g.count
print g(3)
print 'g count =',g.count
```

Edit: Added fcount(), which doesn't do anything much, and details about error.

Comment: "on that line" on which line?

Comment: Before "that line", What is ``fcount``?

Comment: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'` means `f` or `g` is `None`, not the attribute. Python functions are objects; they can have attributes just like many other object types.

Comment: Added some details to answer those questions.

Comment: Is this just a roundabout way of asking, "how do I construct a decorator that counts how many times a function has been called, and how do I access that number?"?

Comment: Actually, given that `fcount` definition, the `f(n)` call in the loop should already cause an error (NoneType object is not callable). Please post a *complete* program that actually displays the error you see.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, that is the ultimate objective, but I want to understand how it works, too.

Comment: @delnan, made a slight change, so it will actually display the error I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let’s start with the definition of `f`:

```
@fcount
def f(n):
    return n+2
```

This defines a `f` as the return value of a call to the function `fcount`, which is used as a *decorator* (the leading `@`) here.

This code is roughly equivalent with

```
def f(n):
    return n+2

f = fcount(f)
```

since the decorator – `fcount` – does not return anything, `f` is `None` *and not a function* at the call site.

In your case `fcount` should return some function and add a `count` attribute to that returned function. Something useful (?) might be

```
def fcount(fn):
    def wrapper(n):
        wrapper.count += 1
        return fn(n)
    wrapper.count = 0
    return wrapper
```

**EDIT**

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, a generalized decorator can forward positional and keyword arguments by capturing them with `*args` and `**kwargs` in the signature and expanding them in the same way when calling another function. The names `args` and `kwargs` are used by convention.

Python also has a helper function (a decorator itself) that can transfer information (name, docstring and signature information) from one function to another: `functools.wraps`. A complete example looks like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def f(a, b, c=None):
   "The useful f function"
   pass

print f.__name__ # `f` rather than `wrapper`
print help(f) # `f(*args, **kwargs) The useful f function` rather than `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is with your "decorator function", `fcount`. A Python decorator function should *return a function*:

```
@decorates
def func(...):
    ...
```

is effectively:

```
func = decorates(func)
```

In your case, the "decorator" `fcount` only `print`s, and won't `return` anything; hence using it will assign `f = None`.

The answer to your more general question is that functions, being Python objects like more-or-less everything else, certainly can have attributes. To actually implement what you want, a decorator that counts how many times the decorated function is called, you could do:

```
def fcount(f):
    """Decorator function to count how many times f is called."""
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        func.count += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    func.count = 0
    return func
```

Comment: Oh, so the decorator function has to return a function, which then becomes the value of the function that called the decorator.  And you make another function inside the decorator function, with the *args and **kwargs, that does the actual work you want done, in this case, incrementing a counter?

Comment: That's right - you create a new function (`func`) inside the decorator function (`fcount`), which in turn (usually) calls the argument function (`f`) with whatever arguments it is passed (`args, kwargs`). This new function is returned by the decorator to replace the original function.

Comment: What if I wanted to put it in a class, rather than a standalone function?  Would I just put the whole thing directly inside a header like:

class fcount2(object):

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You can decorate class or instance methods, but the decorator would still be a standalone function, not itself a class.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was asking if classes can be decorated, too, or just functions.

Comment: On the same basis, you can create a function that takes a class argument and returns a class; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/python-class-decorator) for more.

Answer (score 0):

### Python functions are first-class objects.

They can have attributes.

This feature is rarely seen in the literature, but it has its uses, such as a simplified closure.

By the way, the kind of counter code you asked about is explained in a Pycon 2014 video about decorators.

**Reference**

- [PEP 232 -- Function Attributes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/)
- [Colton Myers: Decorators: A Powerful Weapon in your Python Arsenal - PyCon 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oyr0mocZTg)