# How can I modify class member variable by decorator in python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

base class:

```
class BaseTest():
    m_list = ['a', 'b']
```

I want to let every instance of BaseTest and modify its member variable by decorator, because I don't want to change code of BaseTest,as

```
m_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then next time:

```
test = BaseTest()
print test.m_list
#Output: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I implement？

Comment: You want to modify it at class level or instance level?

Comment: class level may be better.

Comment: `m_list` is not an instance member, but a class member, thus there is no 'its' for instances with regard to it.

Comment: Of course m_list is class member, but every instance can access it. What I want is m_list in every instance print as ```['a', 'b', 'c']```

Comment: Your words aren't put together in a meaningful way. It's impossible to tell what you're asking. As a wild guess, does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances) answer your question?

Comment: If you want every instance to have `m_list` as `['a', 'b', 'c']`, why don't you just set that as the value in the class?

Comment: It is not a nice way to change code of BaseTest() for some reason. I want to write a monkey patch using decorator.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/python-class-decorator) helps you: There is an [answer using a metaclass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/682052/923794) and an [answer using a class decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/682242/923794). Of course, inheritance is recommended everywhere, so I don't even repeat that here. MonkeyPatching is often best done with inheritance in Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
def dec(cls):
    cls.m_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return cls

@dec
class BaseTest():
    m_list = ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# here you have a class
class BaseTest():
    m_list = ['a', 'b']
    quantity=12345

# here you extending from existing class
class BaseTestextended(BaseTest):
    m_list = ['a', 'b','c']

bte= BaseTestExtended()
bte.mlist # outputs ['a','b','c']
bte.quantity # outputs 12345
```

if you want object return modified params by function, you can do like this:

```
class BaseTestextended(BaseTest):
    @classmethod
    def mlist(self):
        return m_list.append('c')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not solve my problem. I perfer Alex Poleha's answer.