# Calling class method as part of initialization

Tags: python

## Current Status

I have an abstract base class that, which hosts data in the form of a numpy array, knows how to work this data, and which can explain matplotlib how to draw it. To accomodate different types of data, it has a number of subclasses, like this:

```
class PlotData():
    """Base Class"""
    subclasslist = []

    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        super().subclasslist.append(cls)

    def __new__(self, initdata, *args, **kwargs):
        for subclass in subclasslist:
            try:
                subclass.__test__(initdata)
            except AssertionError:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            raise TypeError("Initdata does not fit any known subclass")
        return subclass(initdata, *args, **kwargs)

class Plot3D(PlotData):
    """Subclass for 3d-plotting data"""
    def __test__(initdata):
        assert Data_is_the_right_kind

class Plot_XY(PlotData):
    """Subclass for for plotting X-Y relations of data"""
    def __test__(initdata):
        assert Data_is_the_right_kind
```

## The Issue

now, the issue is how to get the class references into the subclasslist. At first I wanted to call super().register() in the class body, but im unable to get a reference to the class itself, which is what I want to store in the list. A small search has yielded two possible solutions, and I was wondering what the best one was.

## Solution 1

Adding a call after each class definition, like this:

```
class Plot_XY(PlotData):
    """Subclass for for plotting X-Y relations of data"""
    def __test__(initdata):
        assert Data_is_the_right_kind
Plot_XY.register()
```

This works, but seems like a very dirty solution to me - a very important part of the class structure is located outside of the body.

## Solution 2

Another possibility could be class decorators. However, I've never used them before, and the examples I've found are generally used to override/add functionality to methods. ([here](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley/blob/master/parsley/decorators.py) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/python-class-decorator), for example). I am familiar with function decorators though, and the following should roughly make clear what I'm aiming for (and a dumbed down version works in the interpreter):

```
def some_creative_decorator_name(cls):
    cls.register()
    return cls
```

or at least, something that functions like Solution 1 but looks like:

```
@some_creative_decorator_name
class Plot_XY(PlotData):
    """Subclass for for plotting X-Y relations of data"""
    def __test__(initdata):
        assert Data_is_the_right_kind
```

It seems to work just as well, but will this screw up stuff like inheritance? That was one of the concerns noted in the linked pages, and I don't really dare count to much on it. (I am not expecting people to subclass it further, but I don't really want to make it impossible if it's desired.)

(Of course other solutions are welcome as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is useless because it's already provided:

```
>>> class A(object):pass
... 
>>> class B(A):pass
... 
>>> class C(A): pass
... 
>>> A.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>]
>>>
```

There is no need to keep your own `subclasslist` when python already provides one for you.

Note that this doesn't include subclasses of subclasses:

```
>>> class D(B):pass
... 
>>> A.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>]
```

However it is easy enough to find all the subclasses:

```
>>> def all_subclasses(klass):
...     for sub in klass.__subclasses__():
...         yield sub
...         yield from all_subclasses(sub)
... 
>>> list(all_subclasses(A))
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>]
```

---

This said, if you want to replicate this functionality it is easier to look at how the default method works. And you'd discover that:

```
>>> '__subclasses__' in dir(object)
False
>>> '__subclasses__' in dir(type)
True
```

So here you can see that it is a method of `type` which is the **metaclass** of `object`. The way to properly replicate this is to write your custom metaclass.

Basically a metaclass is similar to the decorator approach however:

- It is more general because you can do stuff before the class is created, control how it is created and do something afterwards. A decorator receives the class object when it is completed and can only do post-creation stuff
- They are inherited, so you don't have to add anything explicit for each class, but only to the base class.

I'm not going into details here. Check out [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/510937)  for more information on metaclasses.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. I never knew about `__subclasses__` before. And it's making my work a lot easier. I'll also read up a bit about metaclasses, which is also new to me.