# Is it possible to modify a class with a decorator

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, decorator

I am writing a class in python for some settings wich looks like this:

```
class _CanvasSettings:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._size_x = _int(kwargs, 'size_x', 320)
        self._size_y = _int(kwargs, 'size_y', 240)
        self._lock_ratio = _bool(kwargs'lock_ratio', True)

    def get_size_x_var(self):
        return self._size_x
    def _get_size_x(self):
        return self._size_x.get()
    def _set_size_x(self, value):
        self._size_x.set(value)
    size_x = property(_get_size_x, _set_size_x)

    def get_size_y_var(self):
        return self._size_y
    def _get_size_y(self):
        return self._size_y.get()
    def _set_size_y(self, value):
        self._size_y.set(value)
    size_y = property(_get_size_y, _set_size_y)

    def get_lock_ratio_var(self):
        return self._lock_ratio
    def _get_lock_ratio(self):
        return self._lock_ratio.get()
    def _set_lock_ratio(self, value):
        self._lock_ratio.set(value)
    lock_ratio = property(_get_lock_ratio, _set_lock_ratio)
```

as you can see I add the block:

```
    def get_something_var(self):
        return self._something
    def _get_something(self):
        return self._something.get()
    def _set_something(self, value):
        self._something.set(value)
    something = property(_get_something, _set_something)
```

For every single setting.
Is it possible to automate this task with a `decorator`?

I would like to do it like this (pseudocode):

```
def my_settings_class(cls):
    result = cls
    for field in cls:
        result.add_getter_setter_and_property( field )
    return result

@my_settings_class
class _CanvasSettings:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._size_x = _int(kwargs, 'size_x', 320)
        self._size_y = _int(kwargs, 'size_y', 240)
        self._lock_ratio = _bool(kwargs'lock_ratio', True)

# Done !
```

Is this possible?
If yes, how?
How to implement the `add_getter_setter_and_property()` method?

---

**Edit:**
There is a pretty similar question here: [Python Class Decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/python-class-decorator)
from the answers there I suspect that it is possible to achive something like I have asked, but can you give me a clue on how I could implement the `add_getter_setter_and_property()` function/method?

---

**Note:**
the `_int()`, `_bool()` functions just return a tkinter Int/Bool-var eighter from the kwargs if the string (f.e. 'size_x') exist or from the default value (f.e. 320).

---

**My Final Solution:**
I think i have found a pretty good solution. I have to add a settings name only once, which imo is awesome :-)

```
import tkinter as tk

def _add_var_getter_property(cls, attr):
    """ this function is used in the settings_class decorator to add a
    getter for the tk-stringvar and a read/write property to the class.
    cls:  is the class where the attributes are added.
    attr: is the name of the property and for the get_XYZ_var() method.
    """
    field = '_' + attr
    setattr(cls, 'get_{}_var'.format(attr), lambda self: getattr(self, field))
    setattr(cls, attr,
            property(lambda self: getattr(self, field).get(),
                     lambda self, value: getattr(self, field).set(value)))

def settings_class(cls):
    """ this is the decorator function for SettingsBase subclasses.
    it adds getters for the tk-stringvars and properties. it reads the
    names described in the class-variable _SETTINGS.
    """
    for name in cls._SETTINGS:
        _add_var_getter_property(cls, name)
    return cls


class SettingsBase:
    """ this is the base class for a settings class. it automatically
    adds fields to the class described in the class variable _SETTINGS.
    when you subclass SettingsBase you should overwrite _SETTINGS.
    a minimal example could look like this:

      @settings_class
      class MySettings(SettingsBase):
          _SETTINGS = {
              'x': 42,
              'y': 23}

    this would result in a class with a _x tk-intvar and a _y tk-doublevar
    field with the getters get_x_var() and get_y_var() and the properties
    x and y.
    """

    _SETTINGS = {}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """ creates the fields described in _SETTINGS and initialize
        eighter from the kwargs or from the default values
        """
        super().__init__()
        fields = self._SETTINGS.copy()
        if kwargs:
            for key in kwargs:
                if key in fields:
                    typ = type(fields[key])
                    fields[key] = typ(kwargs[key])
                else:
                    raise KeyError(key)
        for key in fields:
            value = fields[key]
            typ = type(value)
            name = '_' + key
            if typ is int:
                var = tk.IntVar()
            elif typ is str:
                var = tk.StringVar()
            elif typ is bool:
                var = tk.BooleanVar()
            elif typ is float:
                var = tk.DoubleVar()
            else:
                raise TypeError(typ)
            var.set(value)
            setattr(self, name, var)
```

after that my settings classes simply look like this:

```
@settings_class
class _CanvasSettings(SettingsBase):

    _SETTINGS = {
        'size_x': 320,
        'size_y': 240,
        'lock_ratio': True
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Class Decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/python-class-decorator)

Comment: @ppperry parts of my question is pretty similar (thanks for the link!), but do you (or somebody else) could give me a clue how I could implement the `add_gett_setter_and_property` method/function?

Comment: Use the `dir` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do what you want, using `setattr` to bind the functions and property as attributes of the class object:

```
def add_getter_setter_property(cls, attrib_name):
    escaped_name = "_" + attrib_name
    setattr(cls, "get_{}_var".format(attrib_name),
            lambda self: getattr(self, escaped_name))
    setattr(cls, attrib_name,
            property(lambda self: getattr(self, escaped_name).get()
                     lambda self, value: getattr(self, escaped_name).set(value)))
```

Here I'm skipping giving names to the `getter` and `setter` methods used by the `property`. You could add them to the class if you really want to, but I think it's probably unnecessary.

The tricky bit may actually be finding which attribute names you need to apply this to. Unlike in your example, you can't iterate over a class object to get its attributes.

The easiest solution (from the implementation standpoint) would be to require the class to specify the names in a class variable:

```
def my_settings_class(cls):
    for field in cls._settings_vars:
        add_getter_setter_and_property(cls, field)
    return cls

@my_settings_class
class _CanvasSettings:
    _settings_vars = ["size_x", "size_y", "lock_ratio"]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._size_x = _int(kwargs, 'size_x', 320)
        self._size_y = _int(kwargs, 'size_y', 240)
        self._lock_ratio = _bool(kwargs, 'lock_ratio', True)
```

A more user-friendly approach might use `dir` or `vars` to examine the classes variables and pick out the ones that need to be wrapped automatically. You could use `isinstance` to check if the value has a specific type, or look for a specific pattern in the attribute name. I don't know what is best for your specific use, so I'll leave this up to you.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. I just have to change `lambda self: return self.getattr(escaped_name)` to `lambda self: getattr(self, escaped_name)`. Would be great if you can fix it for the next one who reads this.

Comment: Ah, that's a rather silly error I made. I've edited to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Decorator for the class.

```
def add_get_set(cls):
    for prop in cls.PROPERTIES:
        # Note cannot be "lambda self: getattr(self, prop)" because of scope prop changes to be the last item in PROPERTIES
        setattr(cls, "get"+prop, lambda self, attr=prop: getattr(self, attr))

    return cls

@add_get_set
class _CanvasSettings:
    PROPERTIES = ["_size_x", "_size_y", "_lock_ratio"]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        for prop in self.PROPERTIES:
            setattr(self, prop, 0)

c = _CanvasSettings()
print(c.get_size_y())
```

You could just set the functions as variables

```
class _CanvasSettings:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._size_x = _int(kwargs, 'size_x', 320)
        self._size_y = _int(kwargs, 'size_y', 240)
        self._lock_ratio = _bool(kwargs'lock_ratio', True)

        for variable in ["_size_x", "_size_y", "_lock_ratio"]:
            setattr(self, "get"+variable, lambda: getattr(self, variable))
            # bind the method (Not sure if binding the method gets you anything)
            #setattr(self, "get"+variable, (lambda self: getattr(self, variable)).__get__(self, self.__class__))
```

Alternate

```
class _CanvasSettings:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._size_x = _int(kwargs, 'size_x', 320)
        self._size_y = _int(kwargs, 'size_y', 240)
        self._lock_ratio = _bool(kwargs'lock_ratio', True)

        for variable in dir(self):
            if variable.startswith("_") and not variable.startswith("__"):
                self.__dict__["get"+variable] = lambda: getattr(self, variable)
```

Comment: While it's possible to add "pre-bound" functions as instance variables this way, you can't do the same with `property` instances. Since they use the descriptor protocol, they really do need to be assigned to the class, rather than an instance.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to automating making properties you could overload `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to detect when a private field is available with an appropriate getter or setter method:

```
class Field: # so I could test it.
    def __init__(self,args,name,default):
        self.name = name
        self.value = default
    def get(self):
        return self.value
    def set(self,value):
        self.value = value

class CanvasSettings:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._size_x = Field(kwargs, 'size_x', 320)
        self._size_y = Field(kwargs, 'size_y', 240)
        self._lock_ratio = Field(kwargs, 'lock_ratio', True)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        private_name = "_" + attr
        field = object.__getattribute__(self, private_name) #this will fail for non-special attributes
        getter = getattr(field,"get",None)
        if getter is None:
            raise AttributeError("Private member did not have getter") #may want to change the error handling
        else:
            return getter()

    def __setattr__(self,attr, value):
        private_name = "_" + attr
        try:
            field = getattr(self,private_name)
        except AttributeError:
            # if there is no private field or there is but no setter
            # resort back to defaualt behaviour.
            return super().__setattr__(attr,value)
        else:
            setter = getattr(field, "set", None)
            if setter is None:
                raise AttributeError("private field does not have a setter")
            setter(value)
```

Then when ever you try to get or set `thing.size_x` it will first look for a `thing._size_x` and check for an appropriate method, here is a demo:

```
>>> thing = CanvasSettings()
>>> thing._size_x.value
320
>>> thing.size_x
320
>>> thing.size_x = 5
>>> 5 == thing.size_x == thing._size_x.value
True
```

Checking for an existing field every time you retrieve the attribute may have penalties to performance but I just wanted to offer this as an alternative if you have many classes with private fields that fit this model.