# Define class attribute for all comparisons

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading, comparator

I have a Python class like this:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    relatives: Iterable['Person']
```

I want to use the `name` attribute for all comparisons, so that `Person` objects are sorted alphabetically by default. Hence, I override the `__gt__()` method like this (as described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__)):

```
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.name > other.name
```

This actually resolves my initial task, I can do e.g.:

```
p1=Person("test1", relatives=[])
p2=Person("test2", relatives=[])
sorted([p1, p2])
Out[4]: [Person(name='test1', relatives=[]), Person(name='test2', relatives=[])]
```

As well as this:

```
p1>p2
Out[5]: False
p1<p2
Out[6]: True
```

I understand that I don't have to implement all operators:

> __lt__() and __gt__() are each other’s reflection, __le__() and __ge__() are each other’s reflection, and __eq__() and __ne__() are their own reflection.

For equality comparison, however, I still have to override `__eq__(other)` explicitly:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Person) and self.name == other.name
```

Is there a way to implement this in a more concise way? I would envision some way to tell the interpreter 'use attribute `name` for all comparisons!'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If providing `__eq__` and at least 1 of rich comparison is okay in your case you might use [functools.total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator, like so:

```
import functools
@functools.total_ordering
class Name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.name > other.name
a = Name("a")
b = Name("b")
print(a<b)
print(a<=b)
print(b>=a)
```

output

```
True
True
True
```

If this is not accepable in your case you would need to prepare own decorator to use, for discussion of decorating class see [How to decorate a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/how-to-decorate-a-class)

Comment: Great, this decorator looks exactly what I have been looking for!
My IDE (PyCharm) still claims that the object does not implement `SupportsLessThanT` when I do, for instance, `min(p1, p1)`, but that might be a PyCharm rather than a Python issue.