# python - "Extending" multiple classes with inheritance/decorators that works with code completion

Tags: python, inheritance, autocomplete, multiple-inheritance, typechecking

I have multiple classes, let's say `OrigClass1` to `OrigClass100` from an external package.

I want to "extend" them, that is add the same set of attributes and methods to each one of them.

I specifically would like for all the attributes/methods from both the original classes and the extension to be "visible" for the purpose of auto-complete and inspection in the IDE.

## Solution 1

I can do that by simply creating a bunch of classes that inherit from the original classes and an extension class:

```
# Code in external package
class OrigClass1:
    def __init__(self, arg_1_1):
        self.val_1_1 = arg_1_1

# a bunch of other classes...

# My extension class
class Extension:
    def __init__(self, arg_ext):
        self.val_ext = arg_ext

    def do_cool_stuff(self):
        print(self.val_ext)

# Define the extended classes
class ExtClass1(OrigClass1, Extension):
    def __init__(self, arg_1_1, arg_ext):
        OrigClass1.__init__(self, arg_1_1)
        Extension.__init__(self, arg_ext)
        
# a bunch more of those...

# All the attributes/methods below are auto completed.
obj1 = ExtClass1(arg_1_1=1, arg_ext="A")
print(obj1.val_1_1)
print(obj1.val_ext)
obj1.do_cool_stuff()
```

**Problem:** The solution above is very cumbersome. I can write a bit of code that will basically produce all those definitions automatically, but that still leaves me with thousands and thousands of lines of essentially useless code. It seems bad for readability and future maintenance.

Preferably, there would be a solution that would allow me to define the inheritance without explicitly defining `__init__`.

## Solution 2 that doesn't actually work

```
# Code in external package
class OrigClass1:
    def __init__(self, arg_1_1):
        self.val_1_1 = arg_1_1

# My extension class
class Extension:
    def __init__(self, arg_ext):
        self.val_ext = arg_ext

    def do_cool_stuff(self):
        print(self.val_ext)

# Define the extended classes
class ExtClass1(OrigClass1, Extension):
    pass

# The following doesn't actually work
obj1 = ExtClass1(arg_1_1=1, arg_ext="A")
print(obj1.val_1_1)
print(obj1.val_ext)
obj1.do_cool_stuff()
```

**Problem:** The above of course doesn't work, because the `Extension` class never gets initialized, and `arg_ext` is being passed to the original class.

## Solution 3 that kind of works

Based on [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/how-to-decorate-a-class), I tried to solve this problem with a decorator.

First, I tried something like this:

```
# Code in external package
class OrigClass1:
    def __init__(self, arg_1_1):
        self.val_1_1 = arg_1_1

# My extension class
class Extension:
    def __init__(self, arg_ext):
        self.val_ext = arg_ext

    def do_cool_stuff(self):
        print(self.val_ext)

# Decorator
def class_extendor(cls):
    init_func = cls.__init__

    def __init__(self, arg_ext, *args, **kwargs):
        init_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Extension.__init__(self, arg_ext)

    cls.__init__ = __init__
    return cls

# Define the extended classes
@class_extendor
class ExtClass1(OrigClass1):
    pass

# All the attributes/methods below are auto completed.
obj1 = ExtClass1(arg_1_1=1, arg_ext="A")
print(obj1.val_1_1)
print(obj1.val_ext)
obj1.do_cool_stuff()
```

**Problem:** That doesn't work, because while the attribute `val_ext` is assigned to the object at initialization, the method `do_cool_stuff` is not. I suppose I could solve this by assigning the extra methods individually.

Regardless however, the resulting class does not offer auto-complete as it is defined at run-time, and seems like at least for now PyCharm is not brilliant enough to be able to deal with that, it seems.

## Solution 4 that doesn't work but it would be great if it did.

```
import typing as t

# Code in external package
class OrigClass1:
    def __init__(self, arg_1_1):
        self.val_1_1 = arg_1_1

ORIG_TYPE = t.TypeVar("ORIG_TYPE")

# My extension class
class Extension(t.Generic[ORIG_TYPE]):
    def __init__(self, arg_ext, *args, **kwargs):
        ORIG_TYPE.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.val_ext = arg_ext

    def do_cool_stuff(obj):
        print(obj.val_ext)

class ExtClass1(Extension[OrigClass1]):
    pass

# All the attributes/methods below are auto completed.
obj1 = ExtClass1(arg_1_1=1, arg_ext="A")
print(obj1.val_1_1)
print(obj1.val_ext)
obj1.do_cool_stuff(obj1)
```

**Problem:** Now the above obviously doesn't work, not only because `ORIG_TYPE.__init__` doesn't make any sense, and also because it still wouldn't be exposing the attributes/methods of the original class. That being said, this "style" of solution somehow intuitively seems possible.

## Questions:

Do you have any recommendations on how to simplify Solution 1, or perhaps are there any solutions that resemble Solution 4? For solution 3, would it be possibly to somehow "forcibly" assign attributes and methods for the purpose of type checker?

Answer (score 0):

So after a long time searching the best (albeit still not perfect) method I've found is based on using metaclasses:

```
# Code in external package
class OrigClass1:
    def __init__(self, arg_1_1):
        self.val_1_1 = arg_1_1


class Extension:
    def __init__(self, arg_ext):
        self.val_ext = arg_ext

    def do_cool_stuff(self):
        print(self.val_ext)


class ClassExtender(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Update the __init__ method of the new class
        def new_init(self, **kwargs):
            # Initialize base classes with relevant kwargs
            for base in bases:
                expected_keys = base.__init__.__code__.co_varnames[1:]
                pass_kwargs = {key: value for key, value in kwargs.items() if key in expected_keys}
                base.__init__(self, **pass_kwargs)

        attrs['__init__'] = new_init
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


# Define the extended classes
class ExtClass1(OrigClass1, Extension, metaclass=ClassExtender):
    pass


# All the attributes/methods below are auto completed.
obj1 = ExtClass1(arg_1_1=1, arg_ext="A")
print(obj1.val_1_1)
print(obj1.val_ext)
obj1.do_cool_stuff()
```

This allows me to:

- define inherited classes without having to redefine `__init__` each time
- and yet on initialization parameters are "separated" for each base
  class
- attributes of methods of both base classes are visible in
  auto-complete/typechecking

It still misses one thing - since `__init__` is overwritten dynamically, inspection throws a warning when passing `arg_ext` in `ExtClass1(arg_1_1=1, arg_ext="A")`. This I can live with, and otherwise the above seems like an elegant solution.

If by some chance someone stumbles on this post and have any additional suggestions, I'd love to hear those.