# How are these type of python decorators written?

Tags: python, language-features, decorator

I'd like to write a decorator that would limit the number of times a function can be executed, something along the following syntax :

```
@max_execs(5)
def my_method(*a,**k):
   # do something here
   pass
```

I think it's possible to write this type of decorator, but I don't know how. I think a function won't be this decorator's first argument, right? I'd like a "plain decorator" implementation, not some class with a ****call**** method.

The reason for this is to learn how they are written. Please explain the syntax, and how that decorator works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I whipped up. It doesn't use a class, but it does use function attributes:

```
def max_execs(n=5):
    def decorator(fn):
        fn.max = n
        fn.called = 0
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            fn.called += 1
            if fn.called <= fn.max:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                # Replace with your own exception, or something
                # else that you want to happen when the limit
                # is reached
                raise RuntimeError("max executions exceeded")
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

`max_execs` returns a functioned called `decorator`, which in turn returns `wrapped`. `decoration` stores the max execs and current number of execs in two function attributes, which then get checked in `wrapped`.

**Translation:** When using the decorator like this:

```
@max_execs(5)
def f():
    print "hi!"
```

You're basically doing something like this:

```
f = max_execs(5)(f)
```

Comment: when applying this decorator, how is the code "translated" by python? For example if my method is called blabla, and I apply the max_execs attribute, how will Python see it? blabla = max_execs(5)(blabla) ?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the translation, but you have the right idea.

Answer (score 4):

Decorator is merely a callable that transforms a function into something else. In your case, `max_execs(5)` must be a callable that transforms a function into another callable object that will count and forward the calls.

```
class helper:
    def __init__(self, i, fn):
        self.i = i
        self.fn = fn
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.i > 0:
            self.i = self.i - 1
            return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

class max_execs:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __call__(self, fn):
        return helper(self.i, fn)
```

I don't see why you would want to limit yourself to a function (and not a class). But if you really want to...

```
def max_execs(n):
    return lambda fn, i=n: return helper(i, fn)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of doing it.  The object-oriented way is to make a class:

```
class max_execs:
    def __init__(self, max_executions):
        self.max_executions = max_executions
        self.executions = 0

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def maybe(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.executions < self.max_executions:
                self.executions += 1
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                print "fail"
        return maybe
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do) for an explanation of `wraps`.

I prefer the above OOP approach for this kind of decorator, since you've basically got a private count variable tracking the number of executions.  However, the other approach is to use a closure, such as

```
def max_execs(max_executions):
    executions = [0]
    def actual_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def maybe(*args, **kwargs):
            if executions[0] < max_executions:
                executions[0] += 1
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                print "fail"
        return maybe
    return actual_decorator
```

This involved three functions.  The `max_execs` function is given a parameter for the number of executions and returns a decorator that will restrict you to that many calls.  That function, the `actual_decorator`, does the same thing as our `__call__` method in the OOP example.  The only weirdness is that since we don't have a class with private variables, we need to mutate the `executions` variable which is in the outer scope of our closure.  Python 3.0 supports this with the `nonlocal` statement, but in Python 2.6 or earlier, we need to wrap our executions count in a list so that it can be mutated.

Comment: if for example a method with the @logged attribute means method = logged(method) , how is a method with a @max_execs(5) "translated"?

Comment: It's the same as saying max_execs(5)(f)

Answer (score 2):

Without relying to a state in a class, you have to save the state (count) in the function itself:

```
def max_execs(count):
    def new_meth(meth):
        meth.count = count
        def new(*a,**k):
            meth.count -= 1
            print meth.count            
            if meth.count>=0:
                return meth(*a,**k)
        return new
    return new_meth

@max_execs(5)
def f():
    print "invoked"

[f() for _ in range(10)]
```

It gives:

```
5
invoked
4
invoked
3
invoked
2
invoked
1
invoked
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
```

Comment: Oops, mipadi was faster with a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

This method does not modify function internals, instead wraps it into a callable object.

Using class slows down execution by ~20% vs using the patched function!

```
def max_execs(n=1):
    class limit_wrapper:
        def __init__(self, fn, max):
            self.calls_left = max
            self.fn = fn
        def __call__(self,*a,**kw):
            if self.calls_left > 0:
                self.calls_left -= 1
                return self.fn(*a,**kw)
            raise Exception("max num of calls is %d" % self.i)


    def decorator(fn):
        return limit_wrapper(fn,n)

    return decorator

@max_execs(2)
def fun():
    print "called"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didn't want a class, but unfortunately that's the only way I can think of how to do it off the top of my head.

```
class mymethodwrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.maxcalls = 0
    def mymethod(self):
        self.maxcalls += 1
        if self.maxcalls > 5:
            return
        #rest of your code
        print "Code fired!"
```

Fire it up like this

```
a = mymethodwrapper
for x in range(1000):
    a.mymethod()
```

The output would be:

```
>>> Code fired!
>>> Code fired!
>>> Code fired!
>>> Code fired!
>>> Code fired!
```

Comment: this can't be used with any method, and uses a callable object. I'd like a regular decorator.