# Python decorator handling docstrings

Tags: python, decorator, docstring

I have a problem using docstrings with decorators. Given the following example:

```
def decorator(f):
    def _decorator():
        print 'decorator active'
        f()
    return _decorator

@decorator
def foo():
    '''the magic foo function'''
    print 'this is function foo'

help(foo)
```

Now the help doesn't show me the docstring of `foo` as expected, it shows:

```
Help on function _decorator in module __main__:

_decorator()
```

Without the decorator, the help is correct:

```
Help on function foo in module __main__:

foo()
    the magic foo function
```

I know, that the function `foo` is wrapped by the decorator, and so the function object is not the function `foo` any more. But what is a nice solution to get the docstring (and the help) as expected?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use `functools.wraps()` to update the attributes of the decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _decorator():
        print 'decorator active'
        f()
    return _decorator

@decorator
def foo():
    '''the magic foo function'''
    print 'this is function foo'

help(foo)
```

Also see the [Standard Library documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) for `functools`.

Comment: This doesn't work if `foo` takes any arguments - they get replaced by whatever the `_decorator` uses. This is a problem especially when you want your decorator to take `*args, **kwds`. I've never been able to find a way to get the docstring correct using `functools.wraps`.

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: The docstring will still be correct even if `foo` takes arguments.  However, `help(foo)` will display the parameter list of the `_decorator`, since it actually replaces the `foo` function.  There's no good way around this if you're writing decorators that take arbitrary arguments using `*args, **kwargs`, but for me the important point is that the docstring is kept intact.  Parameter details could always be specified in the docstring for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I've recently been failing to get the help description correct for decorated functions - it seems a pretty poor state of affairs, but I understand the difficulty as the decorated function could have a completely different signature. Still, there must be a way... :)

Comment: There is a way to do it. The decorator module http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator does it by using a trick. The trick is to rebuild the decorator signature and run exec on it. You can find the trick in line 118 in decorator.py. I think however that this approach is extreme.

Comment: It seems that functools.wraps **does** enable `help()` to work properly now. I'm struggling to find when this changed but I'm still using Python 2.7. Happy day!

Comment: How would I use this method with the docorator `@classmethod`?

Comment: What about putting a line like `_decorator.__doc__ += '\n(decorated by <decorator description>)'` right before `return _decorator`? Seems like that would make the docstring more informative but I haven't seen that so wondering if there is a reason not to do that.

Answer (score 22):

I found a solution, but don't know if it's really nice:

```
def decorator(f):
    def _decorator():
        print 'decorator active'
        f()
    _decorator.__name__=f.__name__
    _decorator.__doc__=f.__doc__
    return _decorator
```

The part with `_decorator.__name__=f.__name__` seems a little bit hideous... What do you think?

Comment: In fact this is (almost ?) exactly what functools.wraps do :)

Comment: It doesn't look hideous to me.  It says exactly what you want it to say.  "I want the name of this function to be 'myfunction' instead of '_decorator'."

Comment: you should not re-invent the wheel, especially when there is a working function from standard library which does this, well-tested, maintained and documented

Comment: I cannot go along with @Azat Ibrakov; I'd always prefer a clear to read solution which is not dependent on any (also eventually changing) libraries. Therefore, I realy like this simple and straight forward approach (+1).

Comment: also, this solution doesn't copy the docstrings of the arguments of `f` (if it had any) and return type. `functools.wraps` does this though.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `functools.wraps`: http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html

Answer (score -1):

The solution is pretty easy. The doc string should be mentioned in the top most decorator that is being called on top of the main function. Find the example below:

```
import math

def wrap2(func):
    def squarer(x):
        return [math.sqrt(i) for i in func(x)]
    return squarer
    

def wrap1(func):
    def summer(x):
        return [i*2 for i in func(x)]
    return summer

def wrap3(func):
    def rounder(x):
        return [round(i,1) for i in func(x)]
    return rounder

def wrap4(func):
    def stringer(x):
        '''
    Enter the input of a 2-dim array to get the output
    '''
        return [str(i)+' rounds ' for i in func(x)]
    return stringer

@wrap4
@wrap3
@wrap2
@wrap1
def rooter(i):
    return [sum(p) for p in i]

help(rooter)

# output
Help on function stringer in module __main__:

stringer(x)
    Enter the input of a 2-dim array to get the output
```

---or----

```
Signature: rooter(x)
Docstring: Enter the input of a 2-dim array to get the output
File:      d:\<ipython-input-392-487fc73b05cf>
Type:      function
```

So, the Doc String must be mentioned in the **wrap4 decorator function** for it to be visible in the main function.