# decorator module vs functools.wraps

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

The functionality of the [`decorator` module](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation3.html) and [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is closely related. What are the differences between the two (as of Python 3.3 / 3.4)?

I am aware of one difference: [3+ years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do#comment1685921_309000), `decorator` supported help, while `wraps` didn't (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-problem-with-docstrings/1782888#comment1670277_1782888)).

Comment: another example: [Preserving signatures of decorated functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/147816/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the main differences is listed right in the documentation you linked to: `decorator` preserves the signature of the wrapped function, while `wraps` does not.

Comment: This seems to be no longer the case, is that correct?

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: You mean that `functools.wraps` now preserves signature?  I don't see anything about that in the docs, but I don't have Python 3.5 installed to test it.

Comment: Agreed its not in the docs, but testing it in the python shell (3.4) seemed to say it does work

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: Doesn't work for me.  What did you test?  Did you read the `decorator` docs linked in the question?  By "preserve signature" we mean that `inspect.getargspec` returns the "real" arguments of arguments of the original functions, not a generic `*args`/`**kwargs` signature.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: Aha, you are right.  `getargspec` is now deprecated and `signature` works properly.

Comment: As per python 3.7: `functools.wraps` preserves signature but only in appearance because `help` and `signature` follow the `__wrapped__` attribute ; it does not raise correct errors in case of misuse. See answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55363013/7262247

Answer (score 6):

Per the discussion with BrenBarn, nowadays `functools.wraps` also preserves the signature of the wrapped function. IMHO this makes the `decorator` decorator almost obsolete.

```
from inspect import signature
from functools import wraps

def dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def dec2(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def foo(a: int, b):
    pass

print(signature(dec(foo)))
print(signature(dec2(foo)))

# Prints:
# (*args, **kwargs)
# (a:int, b)
```

Note that one has to use `signature` and not `getargspec`. Tested with python 3.4.

Comment: `getargspec` or newer and recommended `getfullargspec` don't work on their own, but when used in combination with `inspect.unwrap` they do: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.unwrap

Answer (score 5):

There are two differences:

- `decorator` truly preserves signature while `functools.wraps` does not, **even in python 3.7**. By signature, I mean `help()` and `signature()` and all the `__dict__` of course, but also that the wrapper raises correct `TypeError` *without executing at all* in case wrong arguments are provided by users. As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102697/7262247), `functools.wraps` *appears* to preserve signature but does not really preserve it.
- with `decorator` you always receive the arguments in `kwargs` when they are not var-positional - this makes it much easier to implement your wrapper. With `functools.wraps` it is much more difficult to get an argument value based on its name, as it might be in `*args`, in `**kwargs`, or nowhere (if it is an optional argument and was not provided by the user)

Since I liked `functool.wraps` API very much but wanted to solve the above two problems, I created [`makefun`](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/). It proposes a generalization of `@wraps` that uses the exact same trick than `decorator`, and even supports signature modifications such as adding and removing parameters. It is already used by several projects, do not hesitate to give it a try!