# Python - using decorator.py to preserve a method docstring

Tags: python, oop, decorator, docstring

I am interested in calling an instance method as both a class method as well as an instance method. This can be done by using the class_or_instance decorator as follows:

```
class class_or_instance(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is not None:
            return lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwds)
        else:
            return lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(cls, *args, **kwds)

class A(object):
    @class_or_instance
    def func1(self,*args):
         # method body
```

Now I can call func1 either as `A.func1(*args)` or `A().func1(*args)`.
However when doing this the docstring of func1 disappears. One way to deal with this would be to use decorator from [decorator.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator/3.4.0/) but I am having trouble getting this to work with a decorator that is a class rather than a function. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

EDIT : `functools.wraps()` won't work correctly in this case. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-problem-with-docstrings?rq=1) on stackoverflow

Comment: Why not use @classmethod or @staticmethod?

Comment: @classmethod will only allow it to behave as a class method. I want to be able to call it either as a class or as an instance method

Comment: If you call a classmethod on an instance, the first parameter is not a reference to the instance ("self") but to its class ("cls"). The only difference to a staticmethod is that this first "cls" parameter is missing, but otherwise they behave the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Basic Descriptor/Decorator

You just need to keep in mind *which* function you should decorate.  Your function is being created in `__get__`, so it won't help to use the wrapper as a decorator, instead, you need to apply it in the `__get__` method.  As an aside, you can use either `functools.update_wrapper` or `decorators.decorator` for this. They work very similarly, except that you have to keep the result of `decorators.decorator` whereas `functools.update_wrapper` returns `None`. Both have signature `f(wrapper, wrapped)`.

```
from functools import update_wrapper
class class_or_instance(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is not None:
            f = lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwds)
        else:
            f = lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(cls, *args, **kwds)
        # update the function to have the correct metadata
        update_wrapper(f, self.fn)
        return f

class A(object):
    @class_or_instance
    def func1(self,*args):
        """some docstring"""
        pass
```

Now if you do:

```
print A.func1.__doc__
```

You'll see "some docstring". Yay!

---

#### Cached property decorator

The key here is that you can only affect what gets returned. Since `class_or_instance` doesn't actually serve as the function, it doesn't really matter what you do with it.  Keep in mind that this method causes the function to be rebound every time.  I suggest you add a little bit of magic instead and bind/cache the function after the first call, which really just involves adding a `setattr` call.

```
from functools import update_wrapper
import types

class class_or_instance(object):
    # having optional func in case is passed something that doesn't have a correct __name__
    # (like a lambda function)
    def __init__(self, name_or_func):
        self.fn = fn
        self.name = fn.__name__

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print "GET!!!"
        if obj is not None:
            f = lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwds)
            update_wrapper(f, self.fn)
            setattr(obj, self.name, types.MethodType(f, obj, obj.__class__))
        else:
            f = lambda *args, **kwds: self.fn(cls, *args, **kwds)
            update_wrapper(f, self.fn)
        return f
```

And then we can test it out...neato:

```
A.func1 #GET!!!
obj = A()
obj.func1 #GET!!!
obj.func1 is obj.func1 # True
A.func1 # GET!!!
obj2 = A()
obj2.func1 is not obj.fun1 # True + GET!!!
```

Comment: Thanks both the techniques you suggested do correctly return the docstrings. However using `decorator.decorator` has an issue with the number of arguments passed to the decorated method, and when the method is called it complains of `TypeError`. On the other hand the `update_wrapper` technique works without a hitch. I am wondering what's the issue with the first technique?

Comment: @rk7 so `decorators.decorator` and `functools.update_wrapper` are *not* setup to be compatible with each other. I don't think you can use `decorators.decorator` because it's not set up to handle methods (that have self as the first argument)...it'd take a lot of hacking around to do it...not sure it's worth it.