# Spyder doesn't display docstring when using @property decorator

Tags: python, spyder, python-decorators, docstring

Using `Ctrl + i` in [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) generally displays the docstring for the object the cursor is at, but for the `B` method in the following code, it returns a red "No further documentation available" message:

```
class A():
    @property
    def B(self):
        ''' This is a docstring. '''
```

If the `@property` decorator is commented out, it works fine. I get that `property` is wrapping around B somehow, but it seems like there should be an easy, built-in way to get the docstring to pass through and I can't find an answer.

Is there a way to get around this? What's the best way to get the [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) interactive help to display the docstring for potentially many class methods that each have the `@property` decorator?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-handling-docstrings) certainly seems related, and may help answer why it behaves in this way, but does that mean I need to subclass the `property` built-in in some way?

**EDIT:** Maybe it's something internal to Spyder, because this works with `@property`:

```
>>> print(A.B.__doc__)    
 This is a docstring.
```

Comment: If you set the doc param of the `property` function (It’s one of the arguments, but I don’t know how to pass it in decorator form), that will be the doc for the property.

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with Spyder itself. The voltage example in the following link says that `property` should pass the docstring through: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: If it helps, I'm using Python 3.5.1 and Spyder 2.3.8

Comment: I’ve never used Spyder, so I’ve got no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that upgrading from Spyder 2.3.8 to Spyder 3.0.1 fixes this issue. The docstring now displays properly.