# How to make Python help() function work well with decorators?

Tags: python, python-decorators, code-documentation

Python has the nice `help()` built-in that displays the doc string of an object. When I use it in the REPL passing a function in my module it nicely displays:

```
>>> help(mymodule.myfunction)
Help on function myfunction in module mymodule.main:

myfunction(parameter=False) -> Dict[str, str]
    Doc string of myfunction
```

But if I use a decorator like `functools.@lru_cache` the help function is somewhat confusing:

```
>>> help(mymodule.myfunction)
Help on _lru_cache_wrapper in module mymodule.main:

myfunction(parameter=False) -> Dict[str, str]
    Doc string of myfunction
```

The doc string is displayed, but the first line of the message is confusing for my users who aren't experienced Python programmers.

Note that I didn't create the decorator, it is from the functools module in stdlib. It looks like [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-handling-docstrings) of using [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) won't work for me.

Can I do something to force the display of the first message even if the function has a decorator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python decorator handling docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-handling-docstrings)

Comment: @SpearAndShield thanks for the tip, but I think it doesn't apply to my case. I've updated the question

Comment: The function *is the result of the decorator now*. If the people who created the function didn't add `wraps` (or manually do the equivalent) then I don't think there is anything you can do, other than maybe writing your own version of the decorator that does (maybe deferring to the one that doesn't do what you want)

Comment: but I think this is actually an issue with `help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following wrapper makes the cached function look more like the original.

```
from functools import wraps

def restore(func):
    @wraps(func.__wrapped__)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

It creates yet another wrapper around your decorated function that restores its type as a function while preserving the docstring.

For example, if you have a function like this:

```
@restore
@lru_cache
def func_dup(x: int):
    """my doc"""
    return x
```

Then, run `help(func_dup)`

```
Help on function func_dup in module __main__:

func_dup(x: int)
    my doc
```

### Why the Difference

I will be using CPython 3.10, which is the latest version as of the time I wrote this answer.

The [`help`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L1687) callable is actually implemented in `pydoc` as a `Helper` object. The magic method [`Helper.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L2004) is defined to call [`Helper.help`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L2047). It then calls [`doc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L1780), which calls [`render_doc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L1753). The `render_doc` function makes up the string that gets printed. Inside this function, it calls [`pydoc.describe`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L1687) for a descriptive name for your function.

Your original `mymodule.myfunction` is a function, so `describe` returns in this branch.

```
if inspect.isfunction(thing):
        return 'function ' + thing.__name__
```

This gives `"function myfunction"`.

However, after you decorate your function with `@lru_cache`, it becomes an instance of the built-in/extension type `functools._lru_cache_wrapper`. I am not sure why it is implemented this way, but the decorated function is not of type `types.FunctionType` anymore. So the `describe(mymodule.myfunction)` function returns on the last line after being decorated.

```
return type(thing).__name__
```

This returns `"_lru_cache_wrapper"`.

The [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/functools.py#L35) function attempts to

> Update a wrapper function to look like the wrapped function

It doesn't restore the wrapper as an instance of `types.FunctionType`. It does, however, reference the original function in the `__wrapped__` attribute. Hence, we can use that to wrap your original function yet again.

### Reference

There is a Python Issue [bpo-46761](https://bugs.python.org/issue46761) that may or may not relate to this issue.

> when using functools.partial() to pre-supply arguments to a function, if you then call functools.update_wrapper() to update that partial object, inspect.signature() returns the *original* function's signature, not the *wrapped* function's signature.

It is primarily on `functools.partial`, which doesn't even preserve the wrapped function's signature.