# Python decorator from another package handling docstrings

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm having a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782843/python-decorator-handling-docstrings). This answers the question when you make your own decorator.

However, when you just import a decorator, what to do then?

Ideally it would looks something like this

```
import functools

@functools.wraps()
@functools.lru_cache()
def func(x):
    "This is a function"
    print('Do something')
```

Comment: A decorator is just a function like any other. A function decorator spits out an object, which typically behaves like the function that was passed to it. If it does not add a reference to the original function as an attribute somewhere on the output object, you're out of luck. Simple as that. You will need very advanced introspection to get to it.