# How do you append to an existing function?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble appending to an existing function.

```
def functionA(self):
  var1 = hi
  var2 = bye

Class A(object):
  def functionB(self)
    var1 = hi  <-- insert functionA here
    var2 = bye
    var3 = "something not in functionA"
```

Sorry I know this is probably basic, but I can't find this anywhere. The closest I've found is here [Python add to a function dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789460/python-add-to-a-function-dynamically/2789626#2789626) . Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thats probably as close as you are going to get. You'd usually do that with inheritance, which is not really append.

Comment: XY problem - what are you trying to ultimately accomplish that can't be done by just **calling** `functionA()` from `functionB()`?

Comment: @millimoose I'm just trying to simplify my code. I want all the variables from functionA in functionB.

Comment: Hm, I  misassumed you were trying to do something needlessly advanced. Whoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def functionA():
    var1 = hi
    var2 = bye
    return (var1, var2)


class A(object):
    def functionB(self):
        var1, var2 = functionA()
        var3 = "something not in functionA"
```

how about that?

Comment: thanks! I wasn't expecting an answer like this, but it works for my application!