# Python - monkey patch fails, why?

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming, python-import, monkeypatching, python-internals

I want to monkey patch on `f(*args, **kwargs)` from an installed module. I use the idea of decorator on my own code, but other methods from the installed module fails to call `f` correctly.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('logging')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = np.asarray([0, 1, 2])
    print(f'a1={a1}')

    a2 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
    print(f'a2={a2}')

    np.array = log(np.array)

    a3 = np.asarray([0, 1, 2])
    print(f'a3={a3}')

    a4 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
    print(f'a4={a4}')
```

The output is:

```
a1=[0 1 2]
a2=[0 1 2]
a3=[0 1 2]
logging
a4=[0 1 2]
```

I would like the result to be:

```
a1=[0 1 2]
a2=[0 1 2]
logging
a3=[0 1 2]
logging
a4=[0 1 2]
```

since `asarray` calls `array` in the source code.

My questions are:
1. Why monkey patch fails? 2. How to fix it?

Comment: ...what are you decorating with your `log` decorator?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist `np.array` methods, my terminology is wrong, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `np.array = log(np.array)` you are changing which function the "public" name `np.array` refers to.

But `np.asarray` is defined in the [`numpy.core.numeric`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L469-L538) module, which has its own "private" name to refer to that function. It is not affected by patching the public name.

You would have to patch the private name:

```
np.core.numeric.array = log(np.array)
```

Comment: In this way, I have to patch both the public name (`np.array = log(np.array)`) and private name (`np.core.numeric.array = log(np.array)`), and every other private name that calls `np.arrray`. Is it possible for me to patch only once?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. However, by patching `np.core.numeric.array`, you already cover a lot of functions.