# Get the name of a decorated function?

Tags: python, django, decorator

here is my decorator:

```
def check_domain(func):

    def wrapper(domain_id, *args, **kwargs):
        domain = get_object_or_None(Domain, id=domain_id)
        if not domain:
            return None
        return func(domain_id, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Here is a wrapped up function:

```
@check_domain
def collect_data(domain_id, from_date, to_date):
    do_stuff(...)
```

---

If I do `collect_data.__name__` I get `wrapper` instead of `collect_data`

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You may want to use [`wraps`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) from `functools`. See the example

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def my_decorator(f):
...     @wraps(f)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...         print('Calling decorated function')
...         return f(*args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @my_decorator
... def example():
...     """Docstring"""
...     print('Called example function')
...
>>> example()
Calling decorated function
Called example function
>>> example.__name__
'example'
>>> example.__doc__
'Docstring'
```

Comment: this is the right answer

Comment: The answer from @Zach Estela is simpler.

Answer (score 104):

functools.wraps is not needed! Just use `func.__name__`

```
import time

def timeit(func):
    def timed(*args, **kwargs):
        ts = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        te = time.time()
        print('Function', func.__name__, 'time:', round((te -ts)*1000,1), 'ms')
        print()
        return result
    return timed

@timeit
def math_harder():
    [x**(x%17)^x%17 for x in range(1,5555)]
math_harder()

@timeit
def sleeper_agent():
    time.sleep(1)
sleeper_agent()
```

Outputs:

```
Function math_harder time: 8.4 ms
Function sleeper_agent time: 1003.7 ms
```

Comment: In the OP's case, `functools.wraps` is not needed, you're right - though, using it still is the better approach in most (other) cases.

Comment: yeah this version doesnt work in some cases, functools wraps is the right choice

Comment: I found this nice [explained example](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Comment: @ManuelG, can you explain how wraps works in some cases that this solution doesn't? From what I can tell, Zach's solution allows me to have one self contained decorator to do exactly what I need (even for the exact use case - i.e., profiling code) so not trying to get biased towards this answer but if you have any counter examples - I'm very much interested. Thanks!

Comment: While this answer suggests how it could be possible to solve the problem from the question it does not really solve it. In your code the decorated function name is not fixed: `sleeper_agent.__name__ == 'timed'`. Besides that `functools.wraps` does not only correct `__name__` it also corrects for example `__doc__`. Certainly do use `functools.wraps` and do not reinvent the wheel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do

Comment: The timing function like this answer [here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#timing-functions) use `@functools.wraps`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to `functools.wraps`, you can check out the [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module which was designed to help with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Answer (score 3):

Check out [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). Requires python 2.5 or higher though, if that's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who needs to access the decorated function name when there are multiple decorators, like this:

```
@decorator1
@decorator2
@decorator3
def decorated_func(stuff):
    return stuff
```

the `functools.wraps` mentioned above solves that.