# Get the name of the caller in decorator?

Tags: python

I have the following decorator:

**my_decorator.py**

```
import functools

def caller_name():
    frm = inspect.stack()[1]
    mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
    return mod.__name__

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, bs_servers):
        self.caller = caller_name() # Get the caller's name
        print(self.caller)

    def __call__(self):
        def decorator(f):
            @functools.wraps(f)
            def wrap(*arg, **kwargs):
                #....
            return wrap
        return decorator
```

And here is the usage:

**my_module.py**

```
deco = MyClass(...)

@deco() # Need the self.caller be 'my_module.py'
def test():
    return 1
```

However, the `self.caller` got the value of `my_decorator.py` instead of `my_module.py`?

Comment: Does this help? https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#who-are-you-really

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887081/get-the-name-of-a-decorated-function