# Unexpected behaviour with decorator

Tags: python, decorator

Let's suppose I have a simple function returning its own name

```py
def foo():
    print(foo.__name__)
```

Of course the output when calling is `foo`.
However, if we now decorate that function with a decorator like this:

```py
def dec(func):
    print(dec.__name__)

    def wrapper(*args):
        print(wrapper.__name__)
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper


@dec
def foo():
    print(foo.__name__)


foo()
```

We get

```
dec
wrapper
wrapper
```

Why is the name of the inner function called here?
`func(*args)` is specifically called, shouldn't it be really the function's name among with `dec wrapper`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of a decorated function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887081/get-the-name-of-a-decorated-function)

Comment: I would like to know the reason, not a solution to this occurence

Comment: Oh, I see. Does this answer your question? [What does functools.wraps do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/308999/4518341) *"When you use a decorator, you're replacing one function with another."*

Comment: @wjandrea good catch. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Do you understand what decorators do? You've assigned the wrapper function to `foo` so *of course* `foo.__name__` is wrapper

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, now I do. I just always set a decorator equal with (in this example):
`dec(foo)()`

Answer (score 1):

As for the reason what the decorator does is replace your original function with the wrapper. So in fact `foo` isn’t `foo` anymore, it is the closure created by combining `wrapper` and `func`.

`wraps` is a trick to transfer such metadata to the newly created function.