# python: why use a wrapper in decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def synchronized(func):
    """Decorator for storage-access methods, which synchronizes on a threading
    lock. The parent object must have 'is_closed' and '_sync_lock' attributes.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def synchronized_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self._sync_lock:
           return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return synchronized_wrapper
```

the code is in whoosh/src/util.py,I can't understand the synchronized_wrapper's effect and the parameters in synchronized_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) from where. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@wraps` decorator is just syntactic sugar for a function closure with argument forwarding. `*args` refers to a tuple of positional args, and `**kwargs` refers to a dict of all keyword args that have been passed to `func`.

Hence if you had:

```
def f(foo, bar=None):
    ...
```

and did:

```
sync_f = someinst.synchronized(f)
sync_f(a, bar=z)
```

it would basically be like calling:

```
f(a, bar=z)
```

but inside the "`with self._sync_lock:`" context manager

Answer (score 0):

Decorating a function causes problems with reflection-based operations, and `@wraps` is designed to make the wrapped function truly simulate the original function.  [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do%20%E2%80%93) lucemia provided has applicable info.