# Decorator and closures

Tags: python, closures, decorator, python-decorators

I am going through the [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators#1594484)
to understand decorator.

In the following example, we see that "method_to_decorate" is accessible to wrapper function because of closures. 
But, I didn't understand how arguments `self` and `lie` are accessible to the wrapper function.

```
def method_friendly_decorator(method_to_decorate):
     def wrapper(self, lie):
         lie = lie - 3 # very friendly, decrease age even more :-)
         return method_to_decorate(self, lie)
     return wrapper

class Lucy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 32

    @method_friendly_decorator
    def sayYourAge(self, lie):
        print "I am %s, what did you think?" % (self.age + lie)

l = Lucy()
l.sayYourAge(-3)
#outputs: I am 26, what did you think?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The returned `wrapper` replaces the decorated function, and is thus treated as a method. The original `sayYourAge` took `(self, lie)` and so does the new `wrapper`.

So, when calling `l.sayYouAge(-3)` you are really calling the nested function `wrapper`, which is by that time a bound method. Bound methods get `self` passed in, and `-3` is assigned to the argument `lie`. `wrapper` calls `method_to_decorate(self, lie)`, passing these arguments on to the original decorated function.

Note that `self` and `lie` are hardcoded into the `wrapper()` signature; it is tightly bound to the decorated function. These were not taken from the decorated function, the programmer who wrote the wrapper knew beforehand what arguments would be expected of the wrapped version. Note that the wrapper doesn't *have* to match arguments with the decorated function at all.

You could add arguments, for example:

```
def method_friendly_decorator(method_to_decorate):
     def wrapper(self, lie, offset=-3):
         lie += offset # very friendly, adjust age even more!
         return method_to_decorate(self, lie)
     return wrapper
```

Now you can make Lucy lie about her age in different ways:

```
l.sayYourAge(-1, offset=1)  # will say "I am 32, what did you think?"
```

Comment: Thanks.. We are sending "sayYourAge" method explicitly to the decorator, but not "self and lie". How it is passed?

Comment: @rajpy: It is hardcoded in the decorator. It's not being sent at all. The decorator is not generic.

Comment: +1 You could also (if this is not too much for OP already), mention `functool.wraps` that is usually used to, hmm... [_decorate decorators_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/309000/548696) ;)

Comment: @Tadeck: One step at a time :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Got it now.