# Beazley 4e P.E.R: square(x) but he passes **kwargs within the wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This example is taken from Beazley, Python Essential Reference 4e,
pg:101.

How is he doing:

```
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

where 'func' is the square-function which takes 1 argument. Earlier in
the chapter he sqawks about how the position and number of arguments
must match in a call/definition or a TypeError would be raised.

Also,

```
@trace
def square(x):
    ...
square = trace(square)
```

trace returns 'callf' so this is equivalent to writing: square = callf
which is fine because since square refers to a new-function-object, you can
call it with `*args, **kwargs`. But, then in `callf` he does `func(*args...`

Given  that we just made 'square' refer to some other object, how is
the original square accessible inside? What mechanism is coming into
play?

```
@trace
def square(x):
    return x*x

enable_tracing = True
if enable_tracing:
    debug_log = open("debug.log","w")

def trace(func):
    if enable_tracing:
        def callf(*args,**kwargs):
            debug_log.write("Calling %s: %s, %s\n" % 
                (func.__name__, args, kwargs))
            r = func(*args,**kwargs) #????????
            debug_log.write("%s returned %s\n" % (func.__name, r))
            return r
        return callf
    else:
        return func
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276839/decorator-and-closures/14276877#14276877 may help a little

Comment: DId you really use the word "squawks" to describe him explaining something to you in writing?

Comment: poetic license :p it's the best book for Python though.. so no offence intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *-prefix means, "Use this sequence of values as the positional parameters to the function." The **-prefix means, "Use this dictionary as the named parameters to the function."  If the sequence is empty, then no positional parameters are passed.  If the dictionary is empty, then no named parameters are passed.

When you define a function with those prefixes, then the unaccounted for positional parameters go into the *-prefixed argument, and the unaccounted for named parameters go into the **-prefixed argument.  So if you define a function like this:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
```

then the function can be invoked with any arguments whatsoever.  If that function then calls another function with those arguments, then it will be called however the wrapper was called.

Note that you can call a function with `(*args, **kwargs)` even if wasn't defined that way:

```
>>> def square(x):
...     return x*x
...
>>> args = (10,)
>>> kwargs = {}
>>> square(*args, **kwargs)
100
```

Because kwargs is empty, there are no named parameters passed to the function. It gets only the one positional arguments in args.

Comment: right, I got that part BUT within the closure, if you do: fname(*args, **kwargs) won't that pass everything into square() which really expects just one arg (assuming you have a user who misuses the class) he has no check for no of args within the closure..