# Python decorating classes and preserving name

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to create decorator for classes which takes `parent_klass` as an argument and modifies original class by inheriting `parent_klass` and returns it. See below implementation of this idea:

```
class HelperClass:
    def helper_method(self):
        print("helper method...")


def inherit_from(parent_klass):

    def wrapper(cls):
        class DecoratedClass(cls, parent_klass):
            pass
        return DecoratedClass

    return wrapper


@inherit_from(HelperClass)
class Foo:
    pass


f = Foo()
f.helper_method()  # prints helper method...
print(Foo.__name__)  # prints DecoratedClass
```

Above code works as I expected except the last `print` line. My problem is that `__name__` attribute of original class (`Foo`) is not preserved and replaced by `DecoratedClass`. How can I apply `functools.wraps` functionality in this case? Is there any other way than using `wraps` function?

**EDIT:** Actually, I want to use this decorate in Django project, in which `__name__` attribute is important for database mapping. This decorator is intended to generate dynamic models that also contains custom managers. Simply inheriting the class without decorator does not solve my problem, since supplied argument ('parent_klass' in this case, but 'custom queryset' class in actual implemetation), is also used in bases class's (`Foo`) methods.

Comment: What would be the advantage of your approach over the normal inheritance?

Comment: In this case, there is no advantage. But this is just a simple example for illustrating the problem. I will use it in other context that I can't use inheritance since multi-level composition exists.

Comment: That does not sound convincing. Especially not when your class returned by the decorator uses inheritance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [functools.wraps equivalent for class decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622235/functools-wraps-equivalent-for-class-decorator)

Comment: @KlausD. what does not convince you? Running above script outputs "DecoratedClass" to the console. Do you need hundreds line of code for convince? In essence, my problem is as shown in above attached few lines of code.

Comment: `@inherit_from(HelperClass)` is a really strange decorater, it appears to do nothing that simply `class Foo(HelperClass)` could do, with no discernible benefit. I'm not sure what "multi-level composition" is, nor how it would prevent regular inheritance, but anyway, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541560/5014455

Comment: @ElginCahangirov I believe Klaus means that he is not convinced the problem is a useful one to solve. Really you are just looking for a way to write a class decorator which preserves the name (and perhaps other things such as the doc string) of the decorated class, and Klaus is commenting that the actual decorator you gave as an example is not a very useful decorator.

Comment: As @kaya3 pointed out already, you could use `type()` and get really weird with it if you wanted to.