# How to implement a decorator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I'm brand-new to decorators and closures, I'm trying to practice with a simple example. When executed it raises an error of:

```
NameError: name 'congratulate' is not defined
```

What do I need to change?

```
"""
A recursive function to check if a string is a palindrome.
"""

@congratulate
def palindrome(phrase):
    characters = [char.lower() for char in phrase if char.isalpha()]
    chars_len = len(characters)

    out1 = characters[0]
    out2 = characters[-1]

    if chars_len <= 2:
        return out1 == out2
    else:
        if out1 == out2:
            return palindrome(characters[1:-1])
        else:
            return False


def congratulate(func):
    if func:
        print('Congratulations, it\'s a palindrome!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(palindrome('Rats live on no evil star'))
```

Comment: What's the difference between the expected behavior and the observed behavior? Is there an error? Does it crash?

Comment: At least add `return func` to `congratulate()`

Comment: It says NameError: name 'congratulate' is not define.  Even when I add the return function.

Comment: Replace 'congratulate' func at top, before 'palindrome' func.

Comment: That was it, thanks @germn!

Comment: @germn, out of curiosity, why does order matter in this case?

Comment: Replacing the order is the first step but the decorator will rename the palindrome function. meaning, when you call ```palindrome('Rats live on no evil star')``` you will get a NameError. You need to use functools.wraps to preserve the naming. see  herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do

Comment: @steve, it actually runs correctly once I replace the order.  Not sure why, based on what you said.

Comment: Are you really sure it is worth speaking about "closures" in the beginning of your question? I don't see where a closure is involved in your code or in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late to the party, but I want to expand.

As noted, the `NameError` in this case is caused by the fact that you use a name before you actually create one. Moving `congratulate()` to the top remedies this.

---

#### Appart from the `NameError` you have two implicit *Logic Errors* relating to Decorator/Function Functionality:

---

**First Issue:**

- *Your `if` clause in `congratulate` **always** evaluates to `True`; you aren't exactly congratulating when a string is a palindrome.*

This is caused by the fact that function objects always evaluate to `True`, so a condition of the form `if func:` will always execute:

```
def f(): 
    pass
if f: 
    print("I'm true!")  
# Prints: I'm true!
```

This is thankfully trivial and can easily be fixed by actually calling the function `if func("test string"):`

---

**Second Issue:**

- *The second issue here is less trivial and probably caused by the fact that decorators can be comfusing. You aren't actually using
  `congratulate()` the way decorators are supposed to be used.*

A decorator is *a callable that **returns** a callable* (callables are things like functions, classes overloaded on `__call__`). What your 'decorator' is doing here is simply accepting a function object, evaluating if *the object* is `True` and then printing congratulations.

**Worst part?** *It is also implicitly rebinding the name `palindrome` to `None`.*

Again, you can see this indirect effect (+1 for rhyming) in this next snippet:

```
def decor(f):
     if f: print("Decorating can be tricky")        

@decor
def f(): 
    print("Do I even Exist afterwards?")

# When executed, this prints:
Decorating can be tricky
```

Cool, our function `f` has been decorated, but, look what happens when we try calling our function `f`:

```
f()
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-0ec059b9bfe1> in <module>()
----> 1 f()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Yes, our function object `f` has now been assigned to `None`, the return value of our `decor` function.

This happens because as pointed out, the `@syntax` is directly equivalent to the following:

```
@decor
def f(): pass

# similar to 
f = decor(f)  # we re-assign the name f!
```

Because of this we must *make sure the return value of a decorator is an object that can afterwards be called again, ergo, a callable object.*

---

So what do you do? One option you might consider would be simply returning the function you passed:

```
def congratulate(func):
    if func("A test Phrase!"):
        print('Congratulations, it\'s a palindrome!')
    return func
```

This will guarantee that after the decorator runs on your `palindrome()` function, the name `palindrome` is still going to map to a callable object.

The problem? This turns out to be a *one-time ride*. When Python encounters your decorator and your function, it's going to execute `congratulate` **once** and as a result only going to execute your `if` clause **once**.

But you need it to run this `if` *every time your function is called*! What can you do in order to accomplish this? Return a **function** that executes the decorated **function** (so called nested function decorators).

By doing this you create a new function for the name `palindrome` and this function contains your **original** function which you make sure is executed each time `palindrome()` is called.

```
def congratulate(func):  # grabs your decorated function
    # a new function that uses the original decorated function
    def newFunc():
        # Use the function
        if func("Test string"):
            print('Congratulations, it\'s a palindrome!')
    # Return the function that uses the original function
    return newFunc
```

`newFunc` is now a function that issues calls to your original function.

The decoration process now assigns the `palindrome` name to the `newFunc` object (notice how we returned it with `return newFunc`.

As a result, each time you execute a call of the form `palindrome()` this is tranlated to `newFunc()` which in turn calls `func()` in its body. (If you're still with me I commend you).

---

What's the final issue here? We've hard-coded the parameters for `func`. As is, everytime you call `palindrome()` function `newFunc()` will call your original function `func` with a call signature of `func("Test String")`, which is **not** what we want, we need to be able to pass parameters.

What's the solution? Thankfully, this is simple: Pass an argument to `newFunc()` which will then pass the argument to `func()`:

```
def congratulate(func):  # grabs your decorated function
    # a new function that uses the original decorated function
    # we pass the required argument <phrase>
    def newFunc(phrase):
        # Use the function
        # we use the argument <phrase>
        if func(phrase):
            print('Congratulations, it\'s a palindrome!')
    # Return the function that uses the original function
    return newFunc
```

Now, everytime you call `palindrome('Rats live on no evil star')` this will translate to a call of `newFunc('Rats live on no evil star')` which will then transfer that call to your func as `func('Rats live on no evil star')` in the `if` clause.

After execution, this works wonderfully and get's you the result you wanted:

```
palindrome('Rats live on no evil star')
Congratulations, it's a palindrome!
```

I hope you enjoy reading, I believe I'm done (for now)!

Comment: Thank you, this was the kind of response I needed to deepen my knowledge!

Comment: You're welcome, flybonzai. If you, or any other future visitor to this question, want to get a more verbose introduction to Decorators, then have a look at the advanced chapters of the 5th Edition of Learning Python by Lutz.

Answer (score 3):

```
"""
A recursive function to check if a string is a palindrome.
"""

def congratulate(func):
    def wrapper(*argv, **kargs):
        result = func(*argv, **kargs)
        if result:
            print('Congratulations, it\'s a palindrome!')
        return result

    return wrapper

@congratulate
def palindrome(phrase):
    characters = [char.lower() for char in phrase if char.isalpha()]
    chars_len = len(characters)

    out1 = characters[0]
    out2 = characters[-1]

    if chars_len <= 2:
        return out1 == out2
    else:
        if out1 == out2:
            return palindrome(characters[1:-1])
        else:
            return False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(palindrome('Rats live on no evil star'))
```

the essence of understanding decorator is

```
@f
def g(args)
```

=>

```
f(g)(args)
```

Comment: http://scottlobdell.me/2015/04/decorators-arguments-python/ i find the blog article explains the concept very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Move the congratulate() function above the function it's decorating (palindrome).