# Idiomatic way to inject parameters with python decorators

Tags: python, decorator

So, this is a 2 part question -

1. Is there an idiomatic way in python to inject a parameter into the function signature when using a decorator?

For example:

```
def _mydecorator(func):
  def wrapped(someval, *args, **kwargs):
    do_something(someval)
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapped

@_mydecorator
def foo(thisval, thatval=None):
  do_stuff()
```

The reason around this is when using SaltStack's runner modules You define funcs within the module, and you can call those functions via the 'salt-run' command.  If the above example was a Salt runner module call 'bar', I could then run:

```
salt-run bar.foo aval bval
```

The salt-run imports the module and calls the function with the arguments you've given on the command line.  Any function in the module that begins with a _ or that is in a class is ignored and cannot be run via salt-run.

So, I wanted to define something like a timeout decorator to control how long the function can run for.

I realize I could do something like:

```
@timeout(30)
def foo():
  ...
```

But I wanted to make that value configurable, so that I could run something like:

```
salt-run bar.foo 30 aval bval
salt-run bar.foo 60 aval bval
```

The above decorator works, but it feels like a hack, since it's changing the signature of the function and the user has no idea, unless they look at the decorator.

I have another case where I want to make a decorator for taking care of 'prechecks' before the functions in the Salt runner execute.  However, the precheck needs a piece of information from the function it's decorating. Here's an example:

```
def _precheck(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ok = False
    if len(args) > 0:
      ok = run_prechecks(args[0])
    else:
      ok = run_prechecks(kwargs['record_id'])
    if ok:
      func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper

@_precheck
def foo(record_id, this_val):
  do_stuff()
```

This also seems hackish, since it requires that the function that's being decorated, a) has a parameter called 'record_id' and that b) it's the first argument.

Now, because I'm writing all these functions, it's not a huge deal, but seems like there's probably a better way of doing this ( like not using decorators to try and solve this )

Comment: I don't know what Python version you're using (I'd guess 2.x from the Salt doc examples), but if you can use Python 3, your decorator could inject a keyword-only parameter with a default that you could optionally override when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to dynamically define decorator arguments is not using the syntactic sugar (`@`). Like this:
`func = dec(dec_arguments)(func_name)(func_arguments)`

```
import json
import sys

foo = lambda record_id, thatval=None: do_stuff(record_id, thatval)
def do_stuff(*args, **kwargs):
    # python3
    print(*args, json.dumps(kwargs))

def _mydecorator(timeout):
    print('Timeout: %s' % timeout)
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _dec_default = 30
    l_argv = len(sys.argv)
    if  l_argv == 1:
        # no args sent
        sys.exit('Arguments missing')
    elif l_argv == 2:
        # assuming record_id is a required argument
        _dec_arg = _dec_default
        _args = 1
    else:
        # three or more args: filename 1 2 [...]
        # consider using optional keyword argument `timeout`
        # otherwise in combination with another optional argument it's a recipe for disaster
        # if only two arguments will be given - with current logic it will be tested for `timeoutedness`
        try:
            _dec_arg = int(sys.argv[1])
            _args = 2
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            _dec_arg = _dec_default
            _args = 1
    foo = _mydecorator(_dec_arg)(foo)(*sys.argv[_args:])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no idiomatic way to do this in python 3.7 as far as I know. Indeed `@functools.wraps` only works when you do *not* modify the signature (see [what does `functools.wraps` do ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102697/7262247))

However there *is* a way to do the same as `@functools.wraps` (exposing the full signature, preserving the `__dict__` and docstring): `@makefun.wraps`. With this drop-in replacement for `@wraps`, you can [edit the exposed signature](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/#easier-edits).

```
from makefun import wraps

def _mydecorator(func):
  @wraps(func, prepend_args="someval")
  def wrapped(someval, *args, **kwargs):
    print("wrapper executes with %r" % someval)
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapped

@_mydecorator
def foo(thisval, thatval=None):
  """A foo function"""
  print("foo executes with thisval=%r thatval=%r" % (thisval, thatval))

# let's check the signature
help(foo)

# let's test it
foo(5, 1)
```

Yields:

```
Help on function foo in module __main__:

foo(someval, thisval, thatval=None)
    A foo function

wrapper executes with 5
foo executes with thisval=1 thatval=None
```

You can see that the exposed signature contains the prepended argument.

The same mechanism applies for appending and removing arguments, as well as editing signatures more deeply. See [makefun documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun) for details (I'm the author by the way ;) )