# Applying functools.wraps to nested wrappers

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators, functools

I have a base decorator that takes arguments but that also is built upon by other decorators. I can't seem to figure where to put the functools.wraps in order to preserve the full signature of the decorated function.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

# Base decorator
def _process_arguments(func, *indices):
    """ Apply the pre-processing function to each selected parameter """
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            params = inspect.getargspec(f)[0]

            args_out = list()
            for ind, arg in enumerate(args):
                if ind in indices:
                    args_out.append(func(arg))
                else:
                    args_out.append(arg)

            return f(*args_out)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap


# Function that will be used to process each parameter
def double(x):
    return x * 2

# Decorator called by end user
def double_selected(*args):
    return _process_arguments(double, *args)

# End-user's function
@double_selected(2, 0)
def say_hello(a1, a2, a3):
    """ doc string for say_hello """
    print('{} {} {}'.format(a1, a2, a3))

say_hello('say', 'hello', 'arguments')
```

The result of this code should be *and is*:

```
saysay hello argumentsarguments
```

However, running help on say_hello gives me:

```
say_hello(*args, **kwargs)
    doc string for say_hello
```

Everything is preserved except the parameter names.

It seems like I just need to add another @wraps() somewhere, but where?

Comment: are you using python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

direprobs was correct in that no amount of functools wraps would get me there. bravosierra99 pointed me to somewhat related examples. However, I couldn't find a single example of signature preservation on nested decorators in which the outer decorator takes arguments.

The [comments on Bruce Eckel's post](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=240845) on decorators with arguments gave me the biggest hints in achieving my desired result.

The key was in removing the middle function from within my _process_arguments function and placing its parameter in the next, nested function. It kind of makes sense to me now...but it works:

```
import inspect
from decorator import decorator

# Base decorator
def _process_arguments(func, *indices):
    """ Apply the pre-processing function to each selected parameter """
    @decorator
    def wrapped_f(f, *args):
        params = inspect.getargspec(f)[0]

        args_out = list()
        for ind, arg in enumerate(args):
            if ind in indices:
                args_out.append(func(arg))
            else:
                args_out.append(arg)

        return f(*args_out)
    return wrapped_f


# Function that will be used to process each parameter
def double(x):
    return x * 2

# Decorator called by end user
def double_selected(*args):
    return _process_arguments(double, *args)

# End-user's function
@double_selected(2, 0)
def say_hello(a1, a2,a3):
    """ doc string for say_hello """
    print('{} {} {}'.format(a1, a2, a3))

say_hello('say', 'hello', 'arguments')
print(help(say_hello))
```

And the result:

```
saysay hello argumentsarguments
Help on function say_hello in module __main__:

say_hello(a1, a2, a3)
    doc string for say_hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def x(): print(1)
...
>>> @wraps(x)
... def xyz(a,b,c): return x


>>> xyz.__name__
'x'
>>> help(xyz)
Help on function x in module __main__:

x(a, b, c)
```

AFAIK, this has nothing to do with `wraps` itself, but an issue related to `help`. Indeed, because `help` inspects your objects to provide the information, including `__doc__` and other attributes, this is why you get this behavior, although your wrapped function has different argument list. Though, `wraps` doesn't update that automatically (the argument list) what it really updates is this tuple and the `__dict__` which is technically the objects namespace:

```
WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS = ('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__',
                       '__annotations__')
WRAPPER_UPDATES = ('__dict__',)
```

If you aren't sure about how `wraps` work, probably it'll help if your read the the source code from the standard library: `functools.py`.

> It seems like I just need to add another @wraps() somewhere, but where?

No, you don't need to add another `wraps` in your code, `help` as I stated above works that way by inspecting your objects. The function's arguments  are associated with code objects (`__code__`) because your function's arguments are stored/represented in that object, `wraps` has no way to update the argument of the wrapper to be like the wrapped function (continuing with the above example):

```
>>> xyz.__code__.co_varnames

>>> xyz.__code__.co_varnames = x.__code__.co_varnames
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

If `help` displayed that function `xyz` has this argument list `()` instead of `(a, b, c)` then this is clearly wrong! And the same applies for `wraps`, to change the  argument list of the wrapper to the wrapped, would be cumbersome! So this should not be a concern at all.

```
>>> @wraps(x, ("__code__",))
... def xyz(a,b,c): pass
...

>>> help(xyz)
Help on function xyz in module __main__:

xyz()
```

But `xyz()` returns `x()`:

```
>>> xyz()
1
```

For other references take a look at this question or the Python Documentation

[What does functools.wraps do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)