# how __name__ change in python decorator

Tags: python

Recently I'm learning Python decorator and the use of `functools.wraps`.

```
def a():
    def b():
        def c():
            print('hello')
        return c
    return b


print a.__name__
#output:a
```

I understand why the output is a.But I don't know how `__name__` change in the following code.

```
def log(text):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print('%s %s():' % (text, func.__name__))
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@log('...')
def simple():
    print('*' * 20)

print simple.__name__
#output:wrapper
```

Why the output is 'wrapper' rather than 'decorator' or 'log'?

Comment: Maybe not so related, but you should have a look at [What does `functools.wraps` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)

Comment: Are you aware how decorators works internally? Rewriting it without syntactic sugar helps a lot in comprehending what happens here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basics:

```
@decorator
def f():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def f():
    pass
f = decorator(f)
```

Decorator with args:

```
@decorator(*args, **kwargs)
def f():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def f():
    pass
decorator_instance = decorator(*args, **kwargs)
f = decorator_instance(f)
```

With knowing so, we may rewrite your example to:

```
def simple():
    print('*' * 20)

log_instance = log('...')
simple = log_instance(simple)
```

Let's analyze what happens in last two lines:

- `log_instance` is a `decorator` function, and text variable within it is equal to '...'
- Since `decorator` (regardless of `text` value) returns function named wrapper, `simple` is replaced with function named `wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

The point of decorators is to *replace* a function or class with what is returned by the decorator, when called with that function/class as argument. Decorators with arguments are a bit more convoluted, as you first call the outer method (`log`) to obtain a "parameterized" decorator (`decorator`), then you call that one and obtain the final function (`wrapper`), which will replace the decorated function (`simple`).

So, to give it some structure,

1. call `log` with `'...'` as argument and obtain `decorator`
2. call `decorator` with `simple` as argument and obtain `wrapper`
3. replace `simple` with `wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

```
@log('...')
def simple(...
```

is equivalent to

```
def simple(...
simple = log('...')(simple)
```

so `log` is actually called, returning `decorator`, which is called with `simple` as argument which is then replaced by `decorator`'s return value, which is the function `wrapper`, thus its `__name__` is `wrapper`.