# Use memory_profiler to profile lines in a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, profiling

UPDATE: In memory_profiler version 0.53 and later one can @profile decorate as many routes as you want. Earlier versions only allowed decorating one route. The below question only applies to those versions of memory_profiler with version <= 0.52

Using the normal `@profile` decorator doesn't work on two or more Flask routes. How do I still get line by line memory usage profiling in two or more Flask routes?

I want to profile /route_one and /route_two:

```
from functools import wraps

from memory_profiler import profile

@app.route("/route_one", methods=["GET"])
@profile
def route_one():
    api_live = ping_api()
    if not api_live:
        return make_response('', 503)
    return make_response('', 200)

@app.route("/route_two", methods=["GET"])
@profile
def route_two():
    api_live = ping_api()
    if not api_live:
        return make_response('', 503)
    return make_response('', 200)
```

When I start up my flask app with the above decorated routes I get this error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrapper
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `profile` decorator isn't using `functools.wraps`, so it doesn't preserve the function name. `app.route` sees both functions as named `'profile'` by the time it executes. Since Flask doesn't allow the same name for multiple routes, it raises an error.

Until memory_profiler fixes this, you can fix this by temporarily specifying the endpoint name when you want to apply `@profile` decorator.

```
@app.route('/one', endpoint='one')
@profile
@login_required
def one():
    return 'one'
```

`@profile` should be above any decorators you want to include in your profiling, and `@route` should be above `@profile` so that it routes to the profiled version of the view.

Answer (score 5):

memory_profiler has been updated to include code to use `@profile` on Flask routes. memory_profiler version >= 0.53 will not have this problem. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/issues/186) for more information.

---

The error is telling us that the same function wrapper is used on two routes that we are attempting to map/decorate over. The way to fix this is to use @wraps. As described here: [What does functools.wraps do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)
@wraps copies the name and the docstring from the inner function on to the outer wrapped function. So if we use @wraps, we can avoid the above error.

But we need to use @wraps inside our decorator definition. Our profile decorator is defined  in the memory_profiler library, so we need to re-write that function to include @wraps.
The memory_profiler profiler function is here https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/blob/master/memory_profiler.py and we will use a modified version of it below which uses @wraps.

Use the below code in your flask app
Decorate your route with @my_profiler

```
from functools import wraps

import memory_profiler
try:
    import tracemalloc
    has_tracemalloc = True
except ImportError:
    has_tracemalloc = False


def my_profiler(func=None, stream=None, precision=1, backend='psutil'):
    """
    Decorator that will run the function and print a line-by-line profile
    """
    backend = memory_profiler.choose_backend(backend)
    if backend == 'tracemalloc' and has_tracemalloc:
        if not tracemalloc.is_tracing():
            tracemalloc.start()
    if func is not None:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            prof = memory_profiler.LineProfiler(backend=backend)
            val = prof(func)(*args, **kwargs)
            memory_profiler.show_results(prof, stream=stream,
                                         precision=precision)
            return val

        return wrapper
    else:
        def inner_wrapper(f):
            return profile(f, stream=stream, precision=precision,
                           backend=backend)

        return inner_wrapper
```

We can now use our fixed profiler with

```
@app.route("/route_one", methods=["GET"])
@my_profiler
def route_one():
    api_live = ping_api()
    if not api_live:
        return make_response('', 503)
    return make_response('', 200)

@app.route("/route_two", methods=["GET"])
@my_profiler
def route_two():
    api_live = ping_api()
    if not api_live:
        return make_response('', 503)
    return make_response('', 200)
```