# Create a decorator that saves methods input - returns 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Im currently using a server-less solution (ML -engine) , and i need from time to time to save data frames of a process in cloud storage. For that i created the method named `save_current_data_frame_to_track` and i would like to convert it into a decorator as following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def save_current_data_frame_to_track(current_data_frame, filename):
    current_data_frame.to_csv(filename + '.csv')
    pass

def save_input_to_track(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, func):
        for arg in args:
            for key, value in locals():
                if type(value) == 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame':
                    save_current_data_frame_to_track( value, key)
            return (func)
        return func_wrapper

rp = pd.DataFrame(data={'time_delta_from': [60, 90, 170],
                                'time_delta_to': [30, 60, 120]},
                        index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)

@save_input_to_track
def add_1(data):
    data['time_delta_from'] = 1
    return data

add_1(rp)
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
 add_1(rp)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: What is the Error that you are getting? Also if you decorator function name is `save_input_to_track` you should put that as `@save_input_to_track` on top of other functions.

Comment: @Mudits just updated my question

Comment: Look at the indentation of `return func_wrapper`, your `save_input_to_track()` function doesn't return anything..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [wraps](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), read details about how to get params of the wrapped function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do). And looks like your code should be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from functools import wraps

def save_current_data_frame_to_track(current_data_frame, filename):
    current_data_frame.to_csv(filename + '.csv')

def save_input_to_track(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, pd.core.frame.DataFrame):
                save_current_data_frame_to_track(arg, 'somefile')
        return func(*args)
    return func_wrapper

rp = pd.DataFrame(data={'time_delta_from': [60, 90, 170],
                        'time_delta_to': [30, 60, 120]},
                  index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)

@save_input_to_track
def add_1(data):
    data['time_delta_from'] = 1
    return data

add_1(rp)
```

for key name as filename, i think the simple solution is use kwarg, here example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from functools import wraps

def save_current_data_frame_to_track(current_data_frame, filename):
    current_data_frame.to_csv(filename + '.csv')

def save_input_to_track(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for key, kwarg in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(kwarg, pd.core.frame.DataFrame):
                save_current_data_frame_to_track(kwarg, key)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper

rp = pd.DataFrame(data={'time_delta_from': [60, 90, 170],
                        'time_delta_to': [30, 60, 120]},
                  index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)

@save_input_to_track
def add_1(data1, data2):
    data1['time_delta_from'] = 1
    data2['time_delta_from'] = 2
    return data1, data2

add_1(data1=rp, data2=rp)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! looks impressive , though i need it to work on any given data frame inputs (for example 2 data frames as input) and their names, see my edit (changed it to key from 'some file')

Comment: added second example

Comment: Almost :) i need it to store the original name of "data1" "data2", i have many methods with data frames to track, i want to use this decorator in many places in my project

Comment: This is why i originally wanted to use `locals()`

Comment: by using `locals` you will still have the name `args` so i update the answer, only you need to change the call of the function by using named parameters.

Comment: glad tohelp you!

Answer (score 2):

There was an indentation problem with your code. Also the way you are returning func is wrong. Following code should work for you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def save_current_data_frame_to_track(current_data_frame, filename):
    current_data_frame.to_csv(filename + '.csv')
    pass

def save_input_to_track(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args):
        for arg in args:
           if type(value) == 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame':
               save_current_data_frame_to_track( value, 'some_file')
        return func(*args)
    return func_wrapper

rp = pd.DataFrame(data={'time_delta_from': [60, 90, 170],
                                'time_delta_to': [30, 60, 120]},
                        index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)

@save_input_to_track
def add_1(data):
    data['time_delta_from'] = 1
    return data

add_1(rp)
```

Comment: @Yehoshaphat Schellekens: It fails at `for key, value in locals():` I couldn't fix it because I don't understand what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks! i want to detect if the object of input is of type DF and save it

Comment: Im now getting the following error: `for key, value in locals():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: In that case you don't need to iterate over locals. args has the dataframe.