# Pass parameters to a decorator Class in Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

I'm trying to write a decorator for a Db Model, to makes this Model serializable

```
def Schema(cls):
    class Schema(marshmallow.ModelSchema):
        class Meta:
            model = cls

    cls.Schema = Schema
    return cls


@Schema
class SerialInterface(sql.Model, InheritanceModel):
    id = sql.Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    transmission_rate = sql.Column(types.Integer)
    type = sql.Column(sql.String(50))

    mad_id = sql.Column(types.Integer, sql.ForeignKey('mad.id'))

    serial_protocol = sql.relationship(SerialProtocol, uselist=False, cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

But I want to pass the nested Objects in this Decorator, Like this:

```
@Schema(nested=['serial_protocol'])
class SerialInterface(sql.Model, InheritanceModel):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
def Schema(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped(cls):
        class Schema(marshmallow.ModelSchema):
            class Meta:
                model = cls

        cls.Schema = Schema
        return cls
    return wrapped
```

And then doing `@Schema(nested=['serial_protocol'])` will work.

How this works is, you create a function that takes arguments and returns a decorator. From there the decorator works like a normal Python decorator.

```
@Schema(nested=['serial_protocol'])
class SerialInterface:
    ...
```

The decorator translates to:

```
SerialInterface = Schema(nested=['serial_protocol'])(SerialInterface)
```

Extra tip, Use `functools.wraps` module :) See [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)

Comment: worked, but if i have two places tha use @Schema, the decorator call  wrapped(cls) without cls arg

Comment: never mind, my bad haha i solved, thanks for the answer :)