# Pass a value or change the return of a decorated function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have two functions `g(x)` and `h(x)` that have both the same `try-except` statement, as shown below:

```
class Ex1(Exception):
    """Custom exception"""
    pass

def f(x):
    if x > 2:
        raise Ex1
    return x
    
def g(x):
    try:
        y = f(x)
    except Ex1:
        return "Custom exception raised"
    return y + 1

def h(x):
    try:
        y = f(x)
    except Ex1:
        return "Custom exception raised"
    return y + 2

print(g(3))
```

Is it possible to replace the `try-except` in `g(x)` and `h(x)` with a decorator, to avoid code repetition?

Basically, I would like specifically that if the exception is raised in `f(x)` then `g(x)` and `h(x)` return a custom string, otherwise the value returned from `f(x)` can be used as variable in `g(x)` and `h(x)`.

Comment: Is it mandatory to catch the exceptions in g and h?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried to implement this and had problems? If so please share your attempts and what the problems are.

Comment: @nagyl: the idea indeed that the exceptions are catched in a decorator that decorates g and h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple function decorator (adapted from [this](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/06/09/python-how-to-create-an-exception-logging-decorator/) article) that returns the function normally if there is no error and returns a custom string if an exception is raised

```py
import functools

def exception(function):
    """
    A decorator that wraps the passed function and returns a custom string if there is an 
    error
    """
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return "Custom exception raised!"
    return wrapper

@exception
def f(a):
    """Simple example demonstrating the wrapper"""
    print(a + 1)
```

Sample usage:

```
>>>f(1)
2
>>>f('spam')
'Custom exception raised!'
```

Calling `f(1)` works as expected but `f('spam')` breaks due to `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` and the try-except block in the `exception` decorator returns `Custom exception raised!"`

**Additional resources:**

- [functools docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html)
- [Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)
- [What does functools.wraps do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was indeed what I was trying to do. It's a pity it doesn't work with input strings

Comment: What do you mean an input string? Like passing an input string to the decorator?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your comment at first. Now everything is clear. Thanks a lot!