# I am trying to write a decorator to test a command for call a function

Tags: python, python-decorators

It seems to me that the error is related in `_input` but im not sure

```
import random
from functools import wraps

_input = input()

def name(command='help'):
    def _name(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if _input == command:
                func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner
    return _name


@name(command='test')
def poo():
    print('5')

@name(command='test_2')
def foo():
    print('Hello')
```

```
>>>test
5
```

*(Sorry for my English)*

Comment: what is `wraps` in your code?

Comment: It looks like the `wraps` from `functools`.

Comment: What is the error that you refer to?

Comment: [here they told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)
@GhostOps

Comment: @quamrana no errors

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @quamrana It doesn't output 5

Comment: Ok, but you don't call any of your functions. Why don't you try adding: `poo();foo()` to the end of your script?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is just a misunderstanding here.  You seem to think that if you run the code and type `test` it should run `poo`.  (ugh, what a name).  But it won't run anything at all, because the only *executed* lines in the script are the imports, the `_input = input()` and the decorators (because decorators are [semantic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together)).

If what you want to do is to run a fn when you type a particular command, use a dict of fns instead:

```py
def poo:
    pass


fns = {"test":poo}

choice = None
while choice not in fns:
    choice = input("Fn: ")

fn[choice]()
```

Note that there is nothing else wrong with your code, and you could just add calls to both fns at the end, if you are trying to test decorators, as a comment notes.

### Decorators

Since there seems to be some disagreement about decorators, the following are equivalent:

```py
@mydecorator(*args)
def fn():
    pass

mydecorator(*args)(fn)
```

Perhaps this makes it clearer where the decorator code is called.

Comment: You know `discord.py`?
I am trying to write something similar
(I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: btw `the only executed line` is not strictly true, The functions `name()` and `_name()` are both called twice.

Comment: @quamrana ?
u know what a decorator is?

Comment: @quamrana true, I was being imprecise.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes, I know what decorators are.

Comment: @2e0byo if use your solution, then decorators are not needed here. Im right?

Comment: @quamrana then where do I call them?

Comment: Indeed.  If you are just trying to call some function based upon user input, the simplest way is to store references to the functions and call that.  The simples way is manually to populate a dictionary.

Comment: @Lolo: (I was only trying to correct a slight error by 2e0byo) The line: `@name(command='test')` directly calls `name()`.

Comment: @Lolo I've updated the answer to show the decorator, and I was indeed being imprecise, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If the question is: `Why doesn't my program output 5`, then the answer is: because you don't call any of your functions.

The simplest solution to this particular problem is to just call the functions and let your decorator do the filtering it was designed for:

```py
...
# code from the OP elided
poo()
foo()
```

Output:

```
test
5
```