# How to chain two decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

How can I make two decorators in Python that would do the following?

```
@bold_tag
@italic_tag
def greet():
   return input()
```

Input: Hello

Output should be

```
"<b><i>Hello</i></b>"
```

Comment: I'm not sure chaining is really your problem. If you can write `italic_tag` correctly, it should be obvious how `bold_tag` should be written.

Comment: Keep in mind that if decorator syntax didn't exist, you'd just define `greet`, then write `greet = bold_tag(italic_tag(greet))`.

Answer (score 1):

They're just regular decorators, nothing to it...

Using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) [makes sure the wrapped function smells like the original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309000/51685).

```
from functools import wraps


def bold_tag(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return f'<b>{fn(*args, **kwargs)}</b>'

    return wrap


def italic_tag(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return f'<i>{fn(*args, **kwargs)}</i>'

    return wrap


@bold_tag
@italic_tag
def greet(s):
    return f"Hello, {s}!"


print(greet("you"))
```

The output is

```
<b><i>Hello, you!</i></b>
```