# How to apply a Python timings decorator to a method within a class

Tags: python, decorator, timing

I am trying to apply the timing decorator described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104010217/http://enja.org:80/2011/03/09/a-python-function-timing-decorator/) to a method within a class instead of a standalone method. How should this be done?

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method wrapper() must be called with SomeClass instance as
first argument (got float instance instead)
```

Comment: Did you try it? It's the same. A function and a method aren't different.

Comment: @agf: Unfortunately, there *is* a difference, although it's not caused by the function/method itself but by the class refusing to turn non-functions into instancemethods (with descriptors and stuff). But it shouldn't apply here, as the actual wrappers are functions themselves.

Comment: @delnan I'm not sure I understand. You're saying if the decorator returned something other than a function, it wouldn't work?

Comment: @agf: Yes. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677747/python-decorators-on-class-members-fail-when-decorator-mechanism-is-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

Thanks to your comment, I think I know what the problem is. This doesn't work:

```
class A:

    @timings
    @classmethod
    def a(cls, x):
       print(x)

A.a(2)
```

for exactly the reason you said.
    TypeError: unbound method wrapper() must be called with A instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

But this does:

```
class A:

    @classmethod
    @timings
    def a(cls, x):
        print(x)

A.a(2)
```

So the order matters. I think what's going on here is that it's fooling the way python handles bound methods: When python looks at the member a, it has to make a decision:

1. Make a bound method
2. Make a class method
3. Do nothing (leave it as it is)

If it gets a regular function, it will do (1), and @timings produces a regular function.

Does this solve the problem?

Comment: The method I am trying to time is a classmethod.

Comment: Oh! In that case I think I know what it might be. I edited my answer: any better?

Comment: If I change the order, with the classmethod decorator at the line above the timings decorator, I get "TypeError: Class-level classmethod() can only be called on a method_descriptor or instance method."

Comment: @Alex van Houten: In that case I am stumped. I know you might not care about this problem any more but I am terribly curious what the problem is, so if you post some code maybe it will become apparent.

Comment: I guess you solved it. Suppose utilities.py has the Timing class, then this script, which I call Timing_classmethod.py, works: "import time
from utilities import Timing
timings=Timing()
class sleep:
    enough_sleep=1.0    
    at classmethod
    at timings
    #(at=@) 
    def sleepytime(cls,somestring):
        time.sleep(cls.enough_sleep)
        print somestring
sleep.sleepytime('done')
print timings" However, I was compiling the Cython version, Timing_classmethod.pyx and that gave the above error message. So it is a Cython thing which may or may not me solved in the latest release.

Comment: I guess this says it all: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/limitations.html#id2